# Closing of 21728625

Tags: discussion, reopen-closed

I think https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21728625/is-there-any-way-to-convert-sql-files-into-liquibase-format-xml-format should not be closed. The motivation is *“Questions asking us to recommend or find a tool, library or favorite off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow **as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam**”*. I fully understand the logic behind this moderation criteria, but here it's clearly **not** a question **about choosing a tool**, it's **a question on how to use a already known one**: Liquibase.

Liquibase support two changelogs format SQL and XML. I am personally in the case where I firstly go with SQL changelog format, but due to a limitation in inclusion mechanism, I have to transform it in XML, quite same problem than the asker. And I don't seek a tool with pros and cons and opinion on it, just the simplest solution, ideally based on Liquibase itself to do the job.

Perhaps it could be reword to better fit the criteria, but I don't see well how to do that.

**Edit:** I probably missed the confirm button in my last edit of the question, so [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/275248/deletion-of-21728625) is now a proposal of rephrasing. Thanks for considering it and possibly undeleting and reopening the question

Comment: Not familiar with the tool, but the question itself say "Is there any automated way for this with a standalone app, a library, plugin or API for any particular languages, or do I have to do it manually?".  Sounds like a tool request to me?

Comment: "Is there any automated way for this with a standalone app, a library, plugin or API for any particular languages, or do I have to do it manually?"  Nope.

Comment: @Will By “Nope”, you mean “Should be close”?

Comment: @PomCompot before flipping out over downvotes, perhaps you should familiarize yourself [with meta](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-meta) because your rant over downvotes is not going to help and your statement is incorrect.  In particular, the section with "Voting is different on Meta" is particularly relavant.  While the description there says "Feature-request" most meta users apply that very liberally.  They tend to use downvotes to express disagreement regardless of the tags.  In this case, the downvotes likely say that "I don't think this question should be opened".

Comment: @psubsee2003 In this case, the tooltip of downvote is misleading and the fact that it is not employed like on SO is also misleading for lot of people coming here without all this ‘tribal’ knowledge. I was thinking comments where the place for expressing disagreements about reopening. Downvoting seems to be a tribal misuse here. I am not flipping (don't care a lot about my rep), just expressing what I see by following SO and meta for quite a long time now. I stop here as it tends to become more and more opinionated. Don't feed the troll than can be me here :-).

Comment: @PomCompot meta has no rep so it isn't about your rep at all, and that particular issue (changing the tool tip) has been [discussed before](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254108/downvotes-on-meta-are-confusing-do-they-really-mean-poor-post-quality-or-jus/254460#254460).

Comment: @PomCompot and the part about flipping out may have been overstatement, but the fact that you tried to remind users about voting on meta and discourage downvoting.  Usually when users complain about voting on their meta posts, it usually backfires.

Comment: @PomCompot:  Voting on Meta is different. Downvotes here frequently signal disagreement. In this case, the downvotes are indicating that people disagree with your request that the question be reopened. I am one of those that totally disagree with your request, unless you substantially edit the content of the question. As it is written, it's a tool or library recommendation and was closed appropriately IMO. If you don't intend it to be such a request, edit it so it doesn't read like one.

Comment: Thanks for time taken for responding and pointers to discussion on Meta voting. One thing you should consider is that first time a user comes on meta for asking for instance the reopening a question, he comes from SO, so he expects the vote system works the same way, unless clearly stated this is not the case (unless he unlikely takes time to read some explanations related to this new usage). No problem with backfire, it's the game and while speaking freely about that I didn't expect broad agreement.

Comment: I don't understand: I edit the question to conform to rules and now it has been deleted. Is it a joke?

Comment: It's asking for links (i.e., point me to things that do what I need).  That's what search engines are for.  It's specifically prohibited here for reasons of rot, spam, etc.  The question still asks for these, so it doesn't conform.  Any easy way to judge a question--Does it clearly state the goals of the developer? Does it specify the technologies used?  Does it clearly state what has been done, and why this did not accomplish the previously stated goals?  If the answer to any or all of these questions is no, then the question probably isn't on topic.

Comment: @Will Perhaps you did not read my rewrite proposal on the link given in my last edit. I hope you find here http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/275248/deletion-of-21728625 something more conform to your expectations.

Comment: Why didn't you edit it before it got deleted?  I'll go peek at the rewrite.

Comment: @Will Before I intend to but probably don't click on submit my edit as explained in other linked meta post. It's my silly mistake but in the same time it doesn't give much time to anybody for editing with a so fast deletion (reopen proposal opened only 17 hours ago, deleted in the delay).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As mentioned in comments : the question contains *words* that almost always leads a question to be closed. Those *words* are

> Is there ... a standalone app, a library, plugin or API to do X

Why ? Because reviewers are not expert in this area, but when they see those words they must push on the "close" button. That's how it works...

IMHO, reformulating the question with something like :

> Is there any automated way for this or do I have to do it manually?

is a legitimate edit:

- Any answerer is still free to recommend an app, a library, a plugin or an API to do that: the original intent of the OP is not modified.
- the question is no more a tool recommendation : the close reason is obsolete and question may be re-opened.

Comment: Ok, I will try to reformulate the question and will provide an answer as I successfully do the thing on my own.

Comment: I think there's a small problem in moderation because a lot of really legitimate questions of this type are zealously closed for very light reasons. In the end, answers will be the same for this one, reformulated or not, so closing is in this case not helpful for the community (whereas this question and other ones are them helpful) and only deserves blind rules observance. I know that with this I will not collect upvotes, but it's clearly my feeling after years here and seeing more and more this kind of closed question.