# Why are Stack Exchange users being biased to non-English speakers?

Tags: discussion, english

I have been seeing a lot of users downvoting questions simply because the original poster is not a native English speaker and the question does not make sense for them.

Some people are confused to think this is an "American site" which is definitely not what Stack Overflow ever stated or will state. This is a site for programmers. Encourage those around you, be constructive, and be positive.  Negativity never helps anyone.

My question to the Stack Exchange community is: Why are we downvoting questions from users that are attempting to actively engage in this community just because of a language barrier?

This is my most recent occurrence to the subject

*https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28132128/need-to-pass-a-variable-to-another-variable-java?noredirect=1#comment44637673_28132128*

This question was put on hold by several administrators and downvoted almost immediately by many users. The question makes perfect sense.  But this is definitely not the first occurrence of the matter.

Comment: I don't see any evidence of language biasing from the linked post? What makes you think downvoting appeared because of spelling or grammatical errors at all.

Comment: I can't speak for @πάνταῥεῖ, but my gut reaction would be to downvote since it's unclear.  Then, I'd take some time to get my head straight and edit it so that it *could* be made clearer.  The real rub with questions asked by someone who's not proficient in English is that they're seldom given that second look.  The question's been edited into shape now; it's up to the OP to come back, clarify and curate the question (like, why is that field where it is?  That doesn't make sense in Java).

Comment: Also, America isn't the only country that speaks English.  It's an English-speaking site, and we should expect that the users of this site have the ability to explain their questions in English effectively.

Comment: The question wasn't down-voted because the OP wasn't a native speaker. It was down-voted because it's a *Help Me! Here is my code* type of question, they didn't even point out any errors or where in the code they need help with. Also the question shows little or no research effort.

Comment: So let me ask this...why is my question being down voted?

Comment: [Downvotes on Meta are confusing: do they \*really\* mean poor-post quality, or just disagreement?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/254108) - Votes on meta are different. They have no impact on reputation, knighthood, or anything. They're only agreement/disagrement votes.

Comment: @mario are you really sure about that knighthood thing?

Comment: @AndrewBarber So, there's a secret badge, isn't it :? 

Comment: @mario Well, it *was* secret! ;)

Comment: http://meta.workplace.stackexchange.com/a/2500/168

Comment: Downvotes just hurt my heart so much...you guys have no idea.  And now I have -20 :)

Comment: Please understand that down-votes on meta don't mean the same as down-votes on the other sites. Here a down-vote just means that someone disagrees with your question's premise and **not** that they're disparaging the *quality* of your question. Also, they don't count towards anything, so please soothe that aching heart of yours.

Comment: I'd have downvoted that mess too.  And don't think [that I don't care about people having issues who aren't native speakers](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/212385/translation-help-review-queue).

Answer (score 36):

> because the original poster is not a native English speaker

I'm not a native English speaker but I've never received a downvote due to this.

> the question does not make sense for them

There's a point beyond which an OP's lack of fluency in English is going to harm *the post* so much that it becomes incomprehensible. If this happens then the **quality of the post** is such that it is not fit for SO. Then it is right to downvote it, and vote to close. When doing this, the issue is not with *the person*. The post is not downvoted because *the person* is not a native English speaker. The issue is with *the post*. The post is being downvoted or closevoted because it is of such quality to warrant a such action.

Answer (score 32):

Stack Overflow is not an *American* site, but it is an *English* site and it always has been. We speak English here exclusively, and everyone here expects a question to be legible and clear in the English language.

There's nothing wrong with a user attempting to do their best to speak to us in the English language and letting a user who speaks it natively clean up any grammar issues present. But if they don't know English enough to even be able to demonstrate their thoughts clearly and the community has absolutely no idea what they're talking about, then the only option is to close it down until such time that it *can* be understood.

Answer (score 2):

The main branch (as I call it) of Stack Overflow that this meta is for, has an official language, English. The problem with these posts is not the people who post them, but us being unable to understand the post, and therefore our inability to help the person receive an answer.

For example, I recently encountered a question where the text was (poor) English, but the variable names and a lot of error messages, screenshots of pages, were in Korean. I do not know Korean, and I could not understand the code because I needed to scroll to figure out what the variables had be used for/rewritten to last (I could not memorize the characters).

I know someone who only speaks German and very little English. She writes her questions on the English Stack Overflow, and translates them into English using software like Google Translate to translate them into English. Then, she uses the translator whenever she logs on to translate the whole page into German, so that she can understand the content.

There are currently other languages supported by Stack Overflow, but each operates on its **own separate subcomain**. Try asking a question in English in the Russian Stack Overflow site, and you will probably be downvoted and the question closed in a very short amount of time. Thus saying, we are not biased against non-English speakers.

Here are the other languages currently with their own Stack Overflow subdomains:

- [English](https://stackoverflow.com/)
- [Spanish](https://es.stackoverflow.com/)
- [Portuguese](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/)
- [Japanese](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/)
- [Russian](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/)

If a person does not speak one of these languages, they can either do what my German friend did, or use a website like cloud.tencent.com (this is not advertising).

It takes questions/answers from sites like Stack Overflow and translates them. Here is an example:
https://cloud.tencent.com/developer/ask/sof/106738672

It is a question I answered on Stack Overflow, and it translated the whole page into Chinese.

I am also pretty certain that you can ask questions on it and it will translate it and ask it on Stack Overflow for you (?)
(I don't want to sign up for it and you can't ask a question without an account there, so if anyone can verify???)

Of course, there are various forums **in many countries** other than Stack Overflow.

So,

1. We are not biased against non-English speakers
2. Non-English speakers can get a ton of support without posting non-English questions/answers on the English stack Overflow
3. There are Stack Overflow sites for other languages too.

Comment: I don't think Google Translate (Google Garbalator?) works if you don't know at least some of the other language. The result is often an incomprehensible mess, especially in technical fields where words often get a different meaning, e.g., [Puppet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Puppet_%28software%29), [Chef](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chef_(software)), and [Blade](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laravel#Features).

Comment: True, but it works well enough to give you a good idea of what it should mean. Also, code can be looked at without translation, and be understood