# I don't speak good English, and I'm not a good developer but a serious beginner. What is my place?

Tags: discussion, comments, bad-questions

It is dangerous to ask a question ingenuously. I have tried searching in the previous questions, but I often find nothing helpful, so I decide to ask.

But there are entitled people who don't like the question and downvote it. But for me it is vital to get expert advice. I cannot participate in a discussion about a former question that is not mine since I don't have sufficient reputation. Is there another way? A more adapted forum, perhaps?

What is the best way to learn and ask without clashing with the sensitivity of entitled experts?

Comment: I've often found [Spell Check Plus](http://spellcheckplus.com/) to be a good source for verifying English grammar and spelling. I've tossed blocks of text posted by non-native speakers in there to make sure I catch everything when editing a post.  Glancing at the [source](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/bf346e31-bf4e-4cdb-b854-f50ac2e020a7/view-source) of your post, I would encourage you to look a bit more into [markdown help](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) to better format your question. Putting in line breaks to match what you have in source will help readability.

Comment: see also: [Why are stack users being biased to non english speakers?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284472/839601)

Comment: Re *"A more adapted forum"*: [Be careful what you wish for](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/392352/why-was-the-decision-made-to-develop-discussions-from-scratch-instead-of-increas#comment1312324_392352).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The main thing you need to do is [ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) that includes [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable examples](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). English can be a barrier, but usually someone will edit the English on questions that are otherwise good.

The [only question you've asked is this one](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/4398376/kouty?tab=questions), so I can't provide more concrete feedback. If you have an example of what you think is a good question, but it was downvoted, please close it here.

Finally, remember that some good questions are still [off-topic for Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and you should [do lots of research before asking a question here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users).

Comment: @kouty: That question is overflowing with rhetoric, fluff, exhortations to help *you*, and a general lack of respect for the effort it takes to read. Consider formatting the prose properly, seriously defluffing and generally getting to the point. I haven't judged the difficulty, completeness, or how easy or hard (maybe even for you using your own words) it is to find a duplicate, but even if I was interested in that sector (I'm not, so no chance of an answer from me, sorry), that's not a question I would want to invest any time on.

Comment: @kouty: It's drowning in fluff. Whether that's all, I haven't taken the additional time to evaluate. But anyway, the comment you left below it isn't helping any.

Comment: @kouty: I'm not sure what you said there just now, sorry.

Comment: @kouty Try to make your question more like [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9189172/1445366). Simply describe what you're doing, what you expect to happen, what's actually happening, and your investigation into why they are different.

Comment: @kouty I don't know of other forums. The issue is not your skill level with computers. The issue is the clarity of your writing.

Answer (score 6):

In this Meta question, as in your [Stack Overflow question](//stackoverflow.com/revisions/29461978/6), you seem to have difficulty asking a direct, coherent question.  I've made an attempt to clean it up in [Rev 7](//stackoverflow.com/revisions/29461978/7).  However, it still has significant problems.

People are more inclined to help you if it appears that you have put effort into asking the question.  In terms of presentation…

- You've rambled on.  Putting everything into one paragraph makes it extremely hard to understand.
- You haven't made use of the formatting tools available to you.  Formatting your code as `code` improves readability.
- Ranting does not help your case *at all* — it just leaves a negative impression.  Asking for advice on Meta SO to help improve your question was the right thing to do, but assuming that your downvotes were due to a sense of entitlement from other users was an unjustified insult.  You should genuinely seek to understand how to improve your question.

In terms of content…

- You've asked more than one question: one about how to manipulate characters in a string, and another about the logic bug.
- You later added a `decaler()` function which had *nothing to do* with those two questions.  It doesn't illustrate the problem you are experiencing — there's no `str.replace()`, no `list.pop()`, no `list.insert()`, no logic bug.  Why don't you post the broken code that you tried to write?

Basically, it's not clear what your problem is, or what you are asking.  The only way to "answer" your question is to write code for you.  Stack Overflow does not like doing that.  Such questions get downvoted even if they are allowed to remain open.

Furthermore, the substitution cipher that you want to implement is a common task.  Have you done research on "Caesar Cipher", "substitution cipher", "ROT 13", etc?  For example, there are a [dozen questions on Code Review about Caesar Ciphers in Python](//codereview.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bcaesar-cipher%5D+%5Bpython%5D+is%3Aquestion).  Perhaps you didn't need to ask a question at all.

Answer (score 1):

Well, in my experience with Stack Overflow you have to look for a problem in your workflow yourself and afterwards prove what the results were.

Instead of simply posting your project source and saying you simply have a problem and can't compile something. So explain your issue thoroughly and I'm sure someone will offer any kind of help.