# Wondering why this question was down-voted so many times, and how I can improve it

Tags: discussion, questions, downvotes, asking-questions, quality-improvement

Coming from a background of almost a decade of VB.NET and now transitioning to C#, I'm often equally frustrated and delighted by the differences I encounter between the two languages, both in the language design themselves and by the way the Visual Studio devs have provided or left out features that *should* exist in support of both languages.

That being said, I asked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29280864/why-arent-all-events-available-and-how-can-i-quickly-generate-handlers-in-c-sh) yesterday on SO.  I was surprised by how many down votes I got and by the lack of negative feedback in support of those votes.  I'm left wondering still *why* my question got so many down votes, as I always try to be conscientious and thorough when asking questions, and I only ask questions which I truly find useful.

Let's consider [this discussion about the justifiability of down-voting questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252677/when-is-it-justifiable-to-downvote-a-question).  In reviewing that post, I don't think my question meets any of the criteria presented in the list of "down vote and move on", and neither do I think my question demonstrates incompetence.  The only thing I *can* say about it is that it doesn't demonstrate any research effort, but let's assume that I did research it before I asked it (which I did), then all I would have been able to say was "I googled this for a while and couldn't find anything remotely close to answering this."  I feel like adding that to a question is an exercise in superfluity that ultimately detracts or distracts from the question which, in my opinion, should be as succinct as possible.

As was pointed out in the comments to my question, one reason it could have been down-voted was because it could be considered a "why" question.  However, as I stated there, there are *many* questions on SO that get quite a few up-votes and *zero* down-votes which are asking "why", like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1359948/why-doesnt-stringbuilder-have-indexof-method) for example.  Furthermore, if you consider my question carefully and read some of the answers, it's pretty clear that my question isn't "why did the VS designers do it this way" (because I didn't know about that at the time) but rather "why does this happen at all", which was later explained to me in the answers, e.g. "Well, it is hidden intentionally. If you look at Control class, HandleCreated event is marked with Browsable(false) which means not to show it in properties window."

The bottom line, though, is that I wanted to know how I can accomplish something in C# which I can easily accomplish in VB.NET.  This was really never addressed or answered.  So, I would appreciate anyone's feedback on what I did to merit so many down-votes and what I could do to improve the question so I can get an answer to what I'm actually looking for.

Comment: ...and, I'm getting down-voted here as well.  I must be totally looking at things the wrong way.

Comment: Don't be concerned with downvotes on meta, because [downvoting is different on meta](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254108/downvotes-on-meta-are-confusing-do-they-really-mean-poor-post-quality-or-jus).

Comment: You're aware the question you say is a why question and not downvoted was asked in '09? Rules changed since then:)

Comment: I was aware it was asked that long ago, but not that rules have changed which would have looked kindly on a question like that in '09 but not today.

Comment: The answer to "Why ${company} designed ${something} ${somehow}" is pure speculation for the vast majority of the cases. It is only marginally answerable in situations where there is a clear design principles behind it (and it helps to have the source too).

Comment: @MichaelT -- that's why I *wasn't* asking that, as I stated pretty specifically in my meta question.

Comment: @MichaelT -- quote, "if you consider my question carefully and read some of the answers, it's pretty clear that my question isn't "why did the VS designers do it this way" (because I didn't know about that at the time) but rather "why does this happen at all""

Comment: Additionally, perhaps this isn't applicable in this case or I'm completely wrong (*this is just a thought*), but new-er user in language **A** with tons of language **B** experience questions a design feature they liked in B that answers show to be of little importance in A. Perhaps some language A fanatics could take this as a bit of an ignorant slight against their beautiful language which is clearly superior to B? *Although I'm sure that wasn't your intention*.

Comment: @DonkeyKong -- I love C#.  But that's kind of irrelevant.  Questions should be up or down-voted based on specific rules, not people's perceived slights.

Comment: @roryap Of course they should be, I completely agree. I'm just offering this as a potential reason on top of the "why" question reasoning. In my limited experience on this site, downvotes aren't *always* explicable, but they usually are.

Comment: "why does this happen at all" is pretty damned close to "why is this the way it is".  Maybe 5% of people will see the distinction?  And maybe 25% of those people will see that distinction as being worthy of not dv-ing and close-voting as subjective?

Comment: Okay, I've modified my SO question based on these comments.  I'm hoping my intent is now clearer.

Comment: I agree it's a good idea not to say "I googled for [time] and could not find anything [similar|identical] to my problem". This is often added to posts by people who have made either limited or no prior effort (and, at least in the tags I frequent, this kind of help vampirism happens a great deal). I don't think your question deserves 5 DV, but perhaps this is what your downvoters were thinking - no research. The trick is to demonstrate effort/research without the trigger phrase above - hard for a question of this type.

Comment: I don't understand the downvotes either, except if they were for lack of research effort. The question is very clear, well-written, and probably useful (I can't judge, no .net experience). If at all, a *why?*-question should be **closed** as "primarily opinion-based".

Comment: @JNYRanger -- I love C# very much, but I have to say it's a shame you feel that way about VB.  Each language, like anything else in life, has its own good and bad attributes (pardon the term overloading).  I started my career using Java, but I've been with all flavors of VB for the past decade.  VB is a great language (gasp!), but saying that is in no way taking anything away from C#.  They're two separate tools in the tool kit.  I can't quite understand what many C# zealots have against VB.  It's almost like it's just a form of fanaticism: I'm a Red Sox fan, so obviously Yankees Suck!!

Comment: SO is a haven of VB haters and they can express their sentiment anonymously. I'm surprised that any question that even dares to mentions VB in the same context as C# isn't downvoted into oblivion

Comment: What's the score of your question (upvotes-downvotes) before you linked it here? It's 18 at the moment, not too bad.

Comment: @Bolu -- it was like 4 up 5 down.  I've made improvements to the question based on comments here and the answer.  It's still garnering a steady stream of down votes in addition to the upvotes it's getting.

Answer (score 62, accepted):

This is a complete guess on my part, but I hope it helps.

The way it is written kind of comes off as "VB and C# are different. Why?"  Your first comments on the top 2 answers both ask "why?".  That makes it feel like you want us to read the minds of the Microsoft devs and explain their reasoning (which we can't possibly do).  Even if that wasn't what you wanted to know, it *sounds* like that is your question.

The fact that you clarified here that you are transitioning from VB to C# helps me understand your intent so much better.  The fact that you had to state here "if you consider my question carefully and read some of the answers, it's pretty clear that my question isn't "why did the VS designers do it this way" (because I didn't know about that at the time) but rather "why does this happen at all"" indicates to me that that may not have been entirely clear in your original post.

If I were going to rewrite it, I might do something like this:

> I am transitioning from VB to C#.  In VB I could do X.  In C# I cannot
>   do X because I can't find items X, Y and Z in the normal spots.  How
>   can I accomplish X in C#?

If you really want to know "why does this happen at all", ask it that way in your question and clarify that you don't want to know what the devs were thinking.  Some people are just going to be annoyed when they feel that you are wasting their time by asking them a question that they can't possibly answer (based on their interpretation of what you wrote).

Comment: Thank you for your great answer.  Please see the changes I've made to my original SO post.

Comment: @roryap That's great advice. It's always better to ask how. The whys should be provided as a part of a good answer - hopefully without you asking for it. Putting the why in front of how makes the question less useful.

Comment: So this was yet another case of 'not all information was in the question'.