# Is up- and downvoting for questions being used in a different way to their purpose?

Tags: discussion, voting

I'm confused about the usage of the voting system. In very short, I understood it from the behaviour of others that like:

- Bad question (e.g. bad quality, off-topic...)► **downvote**
- Helpful question (e.g. shows effort, well-researched...) ► **upvote**

According to the privileges:

- **[Upvote](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up)**

  > Whenever you encounter a question, answer or comment that you feel is especially useful, vote it up!
- **[Downvote](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-down)**

  > Use your downvotes whenever you encounter an egregiously sloppy, no-effort-expended post, or an answer that is clearly and perhaps dangerously incorrect.

And according to the tooltips of the question down- & upvote-button

- **Downvote:**

  > This question does not show any research effort; is unclear or not useful
- **Upvote:**

  > This question shows research effort;is useful and clear

But looking around, it appears to be those [reasons](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/296833/idea-for-improving-the-feedback-of-downvotes):

> - The question is too simple for them.
>
>   - The question is too hard for them to understand.
>   - Poor question grammar.
>   - Poorly explained question.
>   - Possible duplicate.
>   - They don't like the topic to which question is related to (programming language, library, software, etc.).
>   - They don't like person who asks the question.

Is my usage of votes wrong or maybe the Tooltips? Should we maybe change our voting behaviour?

Comment: Where do you see the discrepancy between the three descriptions?

Comment: It's not as if the descriptions are contradicting each other.

Comment: I see the problem that questions are downvoted because of beeing too easy or too hard, or duplicate... which isn't the purpose according to the descriptions

Comment: What is your voting behavior based on the tooltips?

Comment: @leAthlon that claim needs examples. Duplicates get downvotes from me because lack of search effort. Too easy can be if the question can be answered from the documentation or any (web)tutorial. Too hard, can't imagine one but if you mean a code dump that ask for a fix I assume we don't have a discussion about that?

Comment: for example,  I wouldn't and I don't downvote because of duplicate. Others do which isn't that like...

Comment: downvoted because of being too easy? => might be a case of no research effort you see there. downvoted because it's a duplicate? => dito, useful duplicates aren't normally downvoted, might even pick up some upvotes. downvoted because of being too hard? => more likely because the question is unclear or too broad. The worst I do with hard questions is deciding I don't want to spend the time and effort for a satisfactory answer, even though I upvote. Might even bookmark it to see what happens.

Comment: okay, let's take an example like this one: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/296833/idea-for-improving-the-feedback-of-downvotes?noredirect=1#comment206413_296833

I've researched, and tried to write it clear and not offending. I've tried to make a proposal. Why are there so many downvotes, what should I've done that it wouldn't be that bad?

Comment: "I don't doubt that downvotes are bad" I disagree. THey are good, if the post deserves them. Anyway, that's a terrible duplicate, as in beating a decayed horse, not even a dead one.

Comment: I don't doubt the purpose of downvotes too, but I doubt the way they're mostly used. I don't quoted the question because I agree its proposal, I quoted because I agree to the mentioned downvoting behaviour

Comment: _Too hard, can't imagine one_ - There is a question where someone is asking for a code implementation of something from a really long academic paper that involves calculus.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Voting is anonymous so we never know the exact reasons users vote. As you seem to be focusing on down votes and the criteria you gathered and I'll indicate if they get my down vote.

- Question is too simple for them.
  *If the answer is one google away, in the doc or tutorial this is a valid reason*
- Question is too hard for them to understand.
   *Unclear I would say, there is not much I don't understand*
- Poor question grammar.
   *lack of effort, don't waste my time if you don't want to spend yours*
- Poorly explained question.
   *not taken the help center guidance into account*
- Possible duplicate.
   *lack of research*
- They don't like topic to which question is related to (programming language, library, software, etc.).
   *I have favorites and ignored tags, I don't see php questions*
- They don't like person who asks the question.
   *I vote on the post not on the user*

It seems you've only posted this question because of the flood of down votes and comments on your earlier proposal. Do know that voting on [meta is different](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-meta). It means disagreement, specially for feature requests. Also note that down votes on meta doesn't change your reputation on the main site.

That particular example got my down vote because it didn't bring anything new to the table. You only suggested to change something but not how or what. That made it look like many of the possible duplicates on that topic.

Comment: so, you are saying that the common down & upvote behaviour is right?
If so- shouldn't we change the privileges explanations?

Comment: I'm not in favor adding even more text that doesn't get read by new users. Unless you have an idea how to fix that?

Comment: well, I've read all my privileges....

I really didn't know about the meta system- my fault, sorry.

At the last question I've looked at the downvote and upvote buttons' tooltips that's why I got to this question- thanks for clarity

Comment: @leAthlon you've done more that I see a lot of ne users do, so keep that up. You seem to be doing fine (except that Unity3d question) so don't worry to much. Here is another meta post that might be of interest: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254108/downvotes-on-meta-are-confusing-do-they-really-mean-poor-post-quality-or-jus and the [meta is murder](http://blog.codinghorror.com/meta-is-murder/) blog post