# Do reputation points decide the quality of answers?

Tags: discussion, reputation, asking-questions

Does this reputation really count to the answerers of your question? My reputation points are really low and I tend to ask a lot of questions but unfortunately never got really quality answer.

Just now I have seen answers to questions that are quite similar to the one I have asked (not duplicate) but of better quality. Is it worth it to ask questions with low reputation points?

Comment: You've said you've seen questions *of better quality* than yours get answers. I think you've already answered your question. If you write good questions you have a better chance of receiving answers and high quality answers in return.

Comment: could you guys please  justify me down voting ? seems like there is no freedom of asking what one wants to ask.Rather than supporting and improving it for future , you people are tend to demoralize others(people like me ). Thank you very much.

Comment: @Roxy keep in mind that downvotes on meta don't work like downvotes on main. Namely, you don't lose reputation and they often express disagreement, not bad content.

Comment: @Roxy voting on meta is different.... Realize people see questions similar to yours at LEAST three times a week (so you'll get downvotes because of "not again?"). Seems like you're not searching for duplicates, since this was already asked, people could downvote because of that. Or the formating of your post

Comment: @Roxy This may help you understand downvotes on Meta. [Downvotes on Meta are confusing: do they *really* mean poor-post quality, or just disagreement?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254108/downvotes-on-meta-are-confusing-do-they-really-mean-poor-post-quality-or-jus)

Comment: You've said yourself that your questions are of low quality, so *that* is the problem, not your reputation.  People with low rep can still ask good questions, just like people with lots of rep can still ask bad questions.

Comment: My read of the question is that the OP's questions are similar to others, but the _answers_ to the other questions are of better quality.

Comment: @JohnnyHK: _"questions that are quite similar to the one I have asked <...> but of better quality."_ - OP

Comment: @Cerbrus I realize that's how everyone seems to be reading this (and I can certainly see why), but it doesn't make sense that someone would realize their questions are low quality and still ask this.

Answer (score 11):

> *"Is it worth to ask questions with low reputation points?"*

It is.

However, users are more inclined to put some effort into answering your questions, if you show you've put some effort into writing the question, yourself.

This means research, proofreading, staying active on the question to reply to comments, things like that.

Nothing is less interesting to answer than a question that's posted without research, with a unclear problem and that full of grammatical and syntactical faults.

*The answers you get are (mostly) only as good as the question you're written.*

Reputation *shouldn't* be a factor in how users vote. However, higher rep users are generally more experienced in participating on the site. This experience can translate into them writing better questions / answers.

So, no. Rep doesn't decide the quality of answers. But I'm convinced it's *loosely* related to the quality of a user's contributions to the site.

But of course, there's always exceptions.

Answer (score 2):

You mentioned that you've seen similar questions of better quality.  That's the primary reason you might see better answers on those questions.  Truly excellent posts are often easier to understand and answer.  The easier you make it on the answerer, the more people will answer.  And they'll often be able to put in more effort because they can concentrate on the core problem instead of focusing on understanding the question.

For example, your meta question is not the most understandable.  Your title question "Does Reputation points decide the quality of answers?" and the body question "Is it worth to ask questions with low reputation points ?" are two separate (even conflicting) questions.  So answerers have to spend more time clarifying your question instead of just answering.  Improper grammar/capitalization turns many people off because they assume you've not put any effort into solving the problem.

> Does [the asker's reputation] decide the quality of answers?

No, you've got the arrow of causality backwards.  Great question askers and answererers have higher reputation *because* their posts are excellent.  There might be a bias towards really low rep users (like < 15 reputation because they won't be able to upvote useful content), but I doubt there is significant bias past that.  However, there certainly is a correlation between low reputation and unclear questions.  Users with lower reputation are often newer to the site and have had less practice posting quality questions and answers.

> Is it worth to ask questions with low reputation points ?

Yes it is.  If your question is on-topic and not a duplicate, **it's still useful to the community** to document problems that people run into.  And it also helps the question asker become more comfortable with posting questions.  If you are willing to listen to feedback from other user comments and take downvotes in stride, you'll be able to better identify how to make your posts high quality.  Even if your question need a bit of polishing, it's still usually helpful to everyone involved if you ask a question that passes the minimum standards that we have.

Comment: I do what I can.  Happy to hear people appreciate my efforts.

Answer (score 1):

> Is it worth to ask questions with low reputation points?

## Yes.

There have been numerous questions asked by low-rep users that received amazing answers. And SO voting guidelines explicitely mention voting *on the question* and its content, not basing on the user, so such question is on fair ground with the ones from high-rep users.

If your questions don't receive answers that are good enough, perhaps think whether you can improve *their content* before looking for outside causes.