# How can I improve my 'too broad' question so it would fit on Stack Overflow (or Programmers)?

Tags: discussion, close-reasons, migration

A few weeks ago, I asked [this question](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/299455/how-to-monitor-record-build-compile-test-time) on Programmers. When writing my question, I was somewhat undecided as to whether to post it on Programmers or Stack Overflow. I would suggest that it could be posted on either site:

- Programmers [on-topic questions](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) include: 'development methodologies and processes'
- Stack Overflow [on-topic questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) include: 'a practical, answerable problem that is unique to software development'

Ultimately, I decided that since the problem was more about a development approach (i.e. monitoring build-times) rather than a programming problem per se, it was probably better suited to Programmers, and so I posted it there. It generated a bit, but not much interest, so I offered a bounty on it.

Then in the space of less than an hour on 16-Oct, 2015, the Programmers question was closed as off-topic, migrated to Stack Overflow ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33178756/how-to-monitor-record-build-compile-test-time)), where the migration was rejected and the question was closed as too broad, but with no further comment or explanation.

- Fundamentally, why was this question closed?

In my view the question is neither off-topic nor too broad for either site. I'm happy to edit the question if that would be helpful, but that would need some indication of what is wrong with it. No one who has voted to close the question (on either site) has provided any indication as to what is wrong with it.

- If, in its current form, the question is not adequate, can you suggest how it might be improved?
- Alternatively, if neither Programmers nor Stack Overflow is the 'right' place for such a question, can you suggest where such a question should belong?

Comment: @downvoter - I'd like to point out that I am following the [SO guidelines](http://stackoverflow.com/help/reopen-questions) by posting this question: "If you're simply unsure about the validity of the closure, the best place to ask is on the community's meta site."

Comment: [Votes are different on meta](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254108/downvotes-on-meta-are-confusing-do-they-really-mean-poor-post-quality-or-jus).  They could just be disagreeing with you and think the question should be closed on SO.  Note that votes on meta do not effect reputation.

Comment: So... they're indicating that they think the SO question should be closed... but not answering this question, which is _why_ they think it should be closed.

Comment: Just to let you know: I've [asked some of the close voters](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/26566486#26566486) to comment on their rationale, just give it some time.

Comment: They could be.  We will never know unless they comment why.  I just wanted you to know it could be a possibility.

Comment: Or they're expressing their disinterest in "please explain the close vote" questions in general. That would be *my* explanation. I didn't vote to close, but would have, as "Too Broad", for exactly the reason stated in the closure: "There are either too many possible answers, or good answers would be too long for this format. Please add details to narrow the answer set or to isolate an issue that can be answered in a few paragraphs." It's either the beginning of a design project or brainstorming session, or a tool request. Neither is a good SO question.

Comment: Side-note: what happened to the bounty when it was migrated? Was it refunded to you? What happened to the bounty (if it migrated) when the question was closed?

Comment: @Tas - I think the Programmers moderator removed the bounty before the Q was migrated. In any case the bounty was refunded on Programmers, and no bounty was placed on the StackOverflow Q.

Comment: Or the downvote could just indicate they don't like when people complain about being downvoted.

Comment: More than one question per question just screams **Too Broad** so this is at least 3 - 4 distinct questions in a single question.

Answer (score 21):

I am the one who initially voted to close the question as too broad.

Quoting the definition of "too broad" from the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions):

> **too broad** - if your question could be answered by an entire book, or has many valid answers, it's probably too broad for our format

Now I'm quoting your question:

> I'd like to be able to monitor/record:
>
> 1. How many times an hour/day a build has been run?
> 2. How much time has been spent running builds?
> 3. If it were possible, to break this down by maven task - i.e. clean/compile/test/other plugins etc.
>
> One approach might be to have the maven output dumped to files, and then have a process to read these/calculate the statistics I want. How should I approach this?

"How should I approach this?" is typically a statement that will attract a lot of valid different answers that may or may not suit your definitive need (or that you may or may not be able to implement regarding the time it would take).

As the question is stated right now, I could come up myself with at least 2 completely different solutions, all of those requiring a very long and detailed answer. The reason is that your question is not specific enough about a particular problem: you have 3 global requirements and a vague idea of how you might implement it but that's it.

On StackOverflow, the policy is that your question is [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) when it covers:

> - a specific programming problem, or
> - a software algorithm, or
> - software tools commonly used by programmers; and is
> - a practical, answerable problem that is unique to software development

Your question does not fit into any of those categories: it is not specific about a programming problem or a software algorithm and, although it does mention Maven, which is used by some (Java) programmers, the answer is definitely not unique.

If I were you, I would try to implement the solution you have thought of and mention in your post. If you hit any specific problems regarding the implementation, please do come back and ask for help on StackOverflow.

As to why your current question was off-topic for Programmers, I am afraid I can't answer that since I've never contributed to this site and I am not aware of their policies. Maybe you could make a meta post on Programmers asking for clarification.

Comment: *"software tools commonly used by programmers; and is a practical, answerable problem that is unique to software development"* - don't those points fit the *"how can you gather statistics on Maven builds?"* question pretty well?

Comment: @Qtax: The point is that the rules on what is and isn't acceptable here go beyond that one sentence.

Comment: The biggest failure of this question that no one has mentioned is **One question per Question!**

Comment: This all comes down to, "How could this question be answered?" The same as with "one question per question," this is ultimately a scoping problem. The ideal answers for this question are either a library recommendation (off-topic) that happens to perfectly fit OP's requirements or a custom-written tutorial. And while custom-written tutorials are nice when they happen, and we reward them, we also have moderation tools in place for when no one can or will go to that extraordinary length.

Answer (score 11):

I was one of the close-voters. 
The question was brought up [in the SOCVR chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/41570?m=26333607#26333607), where Tunaki asked us to take a look at it as he thought it was too broad and not a good fit for Stack Overflow<sup>1</sup>.

Your question asked for approaches to a high-level issue: Recording build statistics for a Java project. 
I do not have much knowledge of Java at all, but such questions can generally be answered in a vast amount of ways (scripts, [Maven](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_Maven) voodoo, IDE ([IntelliJ](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IntelliJ_IDEA)) configurations, and tools). 
Without getting more specifics what is already configured, what **exists**, I felt that this question was little more than a program description and/or a hidden tool request and that answers would either be pointers at technologies (meh) or would get very long descriptions on how to set up such a tool.

I'm not sure how you could improve it. You could show some scripts, explain what already exists, maybe what doesn't work. Bring in some concrete stuff, not ideas.

I can be wrong of course, if you think that I am feel free to comment and explain me why.

---

<sup>1</sup>: That's what [cv-pls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cv-pls) means in chat. Tunaki did not ask us to close the question, he brought it to our attention for us to judge if it should be closed or not. We're not robots.<sup>2</sup>

<sup>2</sup>: Well, we do have Closey, sd, TinyGiant... And let's not get started on the cyborgs.