# Stack Overflow and Stack Overflow {in some language} users should share the reputation

Tags: feature-request, reputation

I created a new account for Stack Overflow en español and wanted to point out a wrong answer in a comment but I didn't have enough reputation for that, even though it's the same Stack Exchange account for Stack Overflow and the Spanish one.

Should not all the Stack Overflow communities share the reputation?

I mean, it's exactly the same topic just with a different language.

Comment: While people may disagree, I don't think thats a reason to downvote... There is nothing wrong with this request, event if it shouldn't be implimented.

Comment: @SethMcClaine on meta voting is different and specially for feature requests a down vote means: don't implement this.

Comment: Obligatory: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254108/downvotes-on-meta-are-confusing-do-they-really-mean-poor-post-quality-or-jus

Comment: This feature request is awesome! More people should upvote it. Sux if you know multiple languages but you don't have the same privileges on all of the sites.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I disagree with the feature request.  They are inherently different communities with different user bases.  Since reputation is a basic measure of that particular community's trust in a user, it's appropriate to have different reputation.

It's worth noting that other communities will sometimes have different reputation requirements for various privileges.  For example, SO in Spanish has adjusted [privilege requirements](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges) to compensate for the fact that it's a relatively new community.  Also, with an [association bonus](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/07/cross-site-account-associations/), you'll be able to jump into new communities pretty quickly by starting at 101 reputation.

Comment: Great! Stackoverflow en español doesn't have that annoying blue *beta* highlight, adiós amigos! :P

Answer (score 8):

> Should not all the Stackoverflow communities share the reputation? I mean it's exactly the same topic just with a different language.

No, I don't think so. While that might make perfect sense for those of you who are bilingual, it does not make sense for the majority of us who are not. (You really don't want me coming to the Spanish site and voting on things, editing, dupe-hammering, etc. with the massive privileges I've accumulated here on the English site.)

Comment: Considering the reach of SO, It's more probable that non bilingual users are the minority, not the majority. Other than that, agree with the answer

Comment: @JustDoIt That's probably true, but the number of people here who speak any specific language (other than English) is almost certainly smaller than the number who don't. I'm not sure how to write this without being confusing. :)