# Synchronize reputation, privileges, and badges across Stack Overflow, Software Engineering, and Code Review portals

Tags: feature-request, reputation, site-crossover

On Stack Exchange there are 3 sites which are more or less targeted to the same audience — software developers, programmers, SWE:

- [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com)
- [Software Engineering](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/)
- [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

What about synchronizing user profiles of these three websites? Firstly, I mean synchronizing reputation, privileges, and badges, which are reflecting the activity of a person on the website. Since these projects are closely connected to each other, I see it logical to share the reputation, privileges, and badges across these sites, just like it currently works on *Stack Overflow* and *Stack Overflow Meta*.

It looks quite strange when a post edit by a person with a 5K+ reputation on *Stack Overflow* is required to pass a peer review on *Software Engineering* or *Code Review* portals.

Answer (score 25):

## No.

These sites are distinct and mutually exclusive from one another.  You do *not* have the same expertise on Code Review as you would Stack Overflow (or Software Engineering).

Effectively, all of what you list - reputation, privileges and badges - are indicators of **participation** on those sites.  Just because you participate (a lot) on one of them doesn't mean you participate on any of the other two.  Additionally, what goes for edits and reviews on one site may not work for another.

The only thing that'd help is actually *participating* on the site.  If you don't participate, you don't get the reputation *or* privileges.

Melding the three across would be...*incorrect*.

Comment: Can you explain why? Mike is saying that since they're all related to software engineering, you would have the same experience in that sense. I know what you mean: you're saying that because they're different communities, with their own unique standards and guidelines, you don't have experience with that community's standards.

Comment: @CodyGray:  I've elaborated a *wee* bit more.  I would almost argue that this is self-evident in the same vein that one doesn't get to pilot an airplane because they know how to drive, but sure...

Comment: As a software engineer, I do perform tasks, related to code design (SWE), code writing (SO), and code reviewing (CR). Of course, the devil is in details, and each of these tasks has its own proportion, but in general, every SWE faces such kind of tasks. Do you know at least one _professional_ SWE (8Y+ of XP), who doesn't do a code review or is not asked to design some functionality/module?

Comment: @MikeB.:  Interns.  But that's likely not your point.

Comment: @MikeB.:  The main premise is that we're not talking cross-expertise.  We're talking *cross-culture*.  Those sites have different cultures about them.  (Software Engineering once *shed* its old culture by changing its name!)  Stack Overflow is the leviathan which will always be the leviathan, and its culture is multifarious and diverse.  The other two sites are a lot more prescribed, chill and straightforward in what they do and do not want.  By merging the profiles together, the leviathan will consume the smaller organisms and be far worse off for it.

Comment: @MikeB.: Just because you know how to do a code review doesn't mean you know how the CodeReview.SE *website* works, its particulars and so forth. You don't know what constitutes a good CR question vs. a bad one. And so forth.

Comment: @MikeB. can you recite at least 3 points on what is not a correct question for CodeReview from [A guide to Code Review for Stack Overflow users](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5777/a-guide-to-code-review-for-stack-overflow-users) *without reading this guide*? (I can't - and I would *not* want to get my 20K+ privileges on either site because of that)

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov, I'll try to summarize it in one sentence: _«A code related question, which is marked on SO as an opinion-based / too broad is a good candidate to CR»_.

Comment: @MikeB.:  Holy crap.  That's *way* wrong.  Please, for the benefit of both communities, don't recommend people to Code Review until you've thoroughly perused that guide.

Comment: @MikeB. hopefully after reading the guide you'll see why we are getting comment/upvote privileges automatically (+100 on any SE site) but not even downvote ones. As Makoto said your sentence is way off guidance which is why granting even free editing privileges would be wrong on other sites.

Comment: @Makoto, _Open-ended questions_ on CR are usually marked as _opinion-based_ or _too broad_ on SO, CR's _Answers can suggest any improvement_ have good chances to be marked as an _opinion-based_ on SO as well.

Comment: @MikeB.:  No, you're just not ready yet.  Seriously.  Read the guide that Code Review prepared for your edification.  The last thing we need right now is more angst because someone decided to recommend Code Review in abject error.

Comment: Anecdotally, *most* recommendations I see in comments or moderator flags to move a question to Code Review or Software Engineering are wrong. That's a pretty good argument for why we shouldn't give moderation-level privileges across communities. Frankly, if we were going to do this, I'd prefer not synchronizing reputation but actually merging the communities into a single site. As long as they are distinct sites, they need to have distinct privileges.

Comment: @CodyGray:  I mean, we talked about [these kinds of comments last year](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/362417/1079354).  I would argue that maybe 1 out of 500 recommendations you see for a question to be moved to CR or SE are actually correct...

Comment: @MikeB 'make this code better' with a dump of your code and nothing else is too broad for stack, so should be fine for CR? Try it out, tell me how you get received. As others have pointed out, carrying the actions/knowing the answers to questions on these other sites Is stuff you (and I, and a lot of SO contributors) know. But their rules could be sometimes as obscure as SO's own rules. You can't know these magically because you know the SO ones. Remember, rep is roughly how much the community trusts you. SO and CR are different communities. Therefore different levels of trust.

Comment: @ToAll, wow, I even could not assume, I will get so sophisticated feedback on such a natural UX optimization idea. After all, `SO`, `SWE`, and `CR` are just different aspects of the same professional field and are regular parts of a weekly tasks.

Comment: BTW, actually, if there is no agreement on sharing profiles even within `SO` on different languages (https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/313292/stack-overflow-and-stack-overflow-in-some-language-users-should-share-the-repu), to propose sharing within `SO`, `SWE`, and `CR` is senselessly.

Answer (score 15):

You may know the answer to any question on any of these sites, but do you know the *rules*?

For example, do you know what the appropriate review decisions on Code Review is in each of these cases?

- A question where the user cannot legally show their code and instead asks how to improve their pseudocode
- A question asking how to speed up code
- A question asking how to improve a solution to a problem from a site like Project Euler
- A question which asks about code that is only an improved version of code from an earlier Code Review question
- An answer that is only code
- An answer with no code
- An answer that suggests to use a different library to solve the problem
- An answer that only addresses one class out of several
- A suggested edit which fixes a bug found in a question's code
- A suggested edit which removed the "meta tag" [beginner](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/beginner)
- A suggested edit to the title that replaces the question "Is this vulnerable to SQL injection" with the statement "Code that allows users to add items to their shopping cart"

See also [Be careful when recommending Code Review to askers](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/253975/6083675)

---

Anyone who has ever gained 200 rep on any one site in the Stack Exchange network gets the association bonus (+100), which allows you to get the most basic of privileges, including flagging, commenting, and upvoting. Two other important privileges are easy to earn from there: downvoting and answering protected questions.

Everything else needs at least some knowledge of the site to do well. After all, you don't want more people doing reviews and deleting answers here that don't know the rules, right?

Comment: # The roadmap to a successful Code Review experience ^^^