# What can we do to keep Stack Overflow sites friendly to newcomers and clean of spam at the same time?

Tags: discussion

I am a new member to **Stack Overflow** and have spent close to two weeks here. I have found it a very useful site for solving problems. You get tons of them in the area which you want to improve.

At the least, it has obviously helped me to refresh my knowledge. On a similar note I am hoping that it has helped other people who are asking the questions. I managed to **reach > 3K** people in this brief period which I consider as a decent testament of my achievement.

Now, over this short period itself, I have also faced a number of people (in some cases people with high reputation points) confrontational or engaging in activities which can easily demoralize you. Obviously, I want to use my name and not remain anonymous. But then it can be costly as the discussions happen on a public stage.

I felt there could have been more constructive ways to resolve issues, but the site allowed people with higher reputation points to downvote and at times leave nasty comments to ridicule your question or answers.

Questions for discussion:

1. Do we encourage such behaviours?
2. How can we protect the interest levels of new joiners to this site (especially those who are using genuine IDs)?

Comment: I'm sorry that it seems critical, but the goal of down-voting is to get rid of bad questions which won't be useful to others. New users need to learn and understand what is or isn't on-topic, or a good question.

Comment: But how do you ensure that all downvotes are necessarily off-topic question? At times, people misread the main question and down voted.

Comment: Now see this question does not have to be down-voted. This site is meant for such discussions and is not an off-topic discussion. But you have chosen to use your opinion to do so.

Comment: You can also down-vote for lack of research, or for questions that are unclear. Some questions *are* on-topic, but still are bad questions.

Comment: The other thing here is I don't even know why someone just downvoted my question. I came here with open mind to understand what we can do to improve this site. This site has good and bad publicity. One of the most popular thing which is there all over the place is old timers do not allow new joiners to succeed. You are just proving my point.

Comment: *"Now see this question does not have to be down-voted. This site is meant for such discussions and is not an off-topic discussion."* Did the person asking the question search for all the other times this question has been asked, and notice that it's a dupe? You're proving that other people ***must do*** what you ask them not to do.  Down vote and/or close. As a new member, surely you appreciate that many others have asked the same question long before you :)

Comment: Why should StackOverflow be friendly to newcomers? Good posts deserve upvotes, even if posted by a newcomer; and bad posts deserve downvotes, even if posted by an user with lots of rep. I mean, only the content matters, not the user. It seems newcomers are negatively biased but that's because most of them don't understand how StackOverflow works. With downvotes they can learn they did something bad, and then improve it.

Comment: [Voting is different on Meta](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254108/downvotes-on-meta-are-confusing-do-they-really-mean-poor-post-quality-or-jus). Downvotes here can mean simple disagreement, not that the post is a bad post.

Comment: @Oriol - Yes, I was referring to people like you. This site is not just meant for experts. It is meant for new people who wants to ask questions and have followed the About Stack Overflow section rules. No where it is mentioned, you cannot ask a question which is stupid from someone's perspective.

Comment: @Suparna Note bad does not mean simple/trivial, and good does not mean expert/difficult. A good question is defined in [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). For example, I have seen questions like "How can I remove the space below my footer?" and an image, but without any code (nor even link to site). Of course I will downvote it, even if the asker thinks I'm being unfriendly.

Comment: @Oriol - Now you are trying to be defensive. I was referring to your comment - "Why should StackOverflow be friendly to newcomers? "

Comment: You'll need to include some specifics if you want meaningful feedback. Vague statements about "confrontational or engaging in activities which can easily demoralize you" and "nasty comments" is not something anyone can really reply to ...

Comment: @Suparna I mean, if somebody asks a good question according to [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), then it shouldn't be downvoted, even if an expert thinks it's trivial to solve.

Comment: So far the only comment I found as really useful was from @EdCottrell. Everyone else has only proved the point which I am stating. Anyway, I will not delete the question as I think it is a genuine ask as I am equally concerned on how one reacts to good posts.

Comment: I really don't see any of these comments as negative, they seem purely factual. Just remember voting is not personal, it's about the content, not the user.

Comment: @AlexanderO'Mara - Agreed. Tell me one reason why this question do not fit here?

Comment: Who said it doesn't fit here? I think it does. It's probably a duplicate of some other questions though, as these issues have been well-covered over the years.

Comment: I think a whole two weeks experience is a little too short to be suggesting site-wide changes. Wait until you've been here two years, when you've learned how the site works, what the quality standards are, and you've dealt with the myriad of poor questions that flood the site from new users, and then you'll have a better understanding and be in a position to think about suggesting changes. New users don't get a special exemption because they're new; they're expected to have spend enough time here before posting to know how the site works. If you didn't do that, shame on you.

Comment: There was no *naming and shaming*. It's a statement of fact - two weeks of experience is not sufficient to suggest site-wide changes to a site that has been working extremely well for several years, and the whole *you should be nicer to new users because they're not familar with the site and they can't be bothered to learn how it works* has been beaten to death already.

Comment: @KenWhite -  You did not say that. You said - "......, shame on you." That is personal by all standards!

Comment: Yes. Shame on you for not learning how the site works before you decided it needs to change. I'd say the same to anyone who suggested a change that could potentially affect millions of others without having any understanding. Shame on you for taking guidelines that have been established over years of experience as a personal insult. And shame on you for resorting to name calling and personal insults rather than an adult discussion.

Comment: @KenWhite - Before you jump to conclusion, read the question. No one suggested make a change? It was call for opinion. I wanted to know about other people's opinions.

Comment: You did suggest a change. *What can we do to...* suggests that a change is needed. What we can do is keep things the way they are, and keep the expectation that before posting on a site you would become familiar with that site, understand the guidelines and culture, take the [tour] (which you agreed to do when creating your account), and understand the site guidelines that are in the [help]. Its not our responsibility to coddle users who can't be bothered to do so.

Comment: I downvoted this because it is a rant about downvotes with an obvious lack of research effort.

Comment: (continued) The biggest thing that keeps SO apart from all of the other sites out there is that we maintain quality standards and specific guidelines. There's no need to reduce those standards for individuals who aren't willing to understand or follow them before asking a question here. And as far as your *vast experience* that entitles you to suggest changes, you may have **reached > 3K people**, but the users who have reached millions of people aren't impressed.

Comment: Downvoting here is disagreement with the content. I want to see if there are any agreements. If there are no upvotes, then I agree on what you said. Not until then. I did not think about ranting....

Comment: @KenWhite - Dude - correction - I have asked for opinions whether we want to do anything? If you have read meta-stackexchange rules, you can just downvote (and if you wish), can leave some useful comment on why you think the present state/standards are good enough and no changes are required.

Comment: Downvoting here on Meta has nothing to do with quality when you're discussing feature changes. In that case, downvoting means people disagree with your ideas. See the FAQ. And I did just that: I posted *useful comments on why I think the present state/standards are good enough and no changes are required*, at which point you called me names and launched personal insults that resulted in *others* (not me) flagging those comments and their deletion.

Comment: What do you think I mentioned when I said - "Downvoting here is disagreement with the content. I want to see if there are any agreements. If there are no upvotes, then I agree on what you said. "

Comment: OK. You've got it. You've received 8 downvotes and zero upvotes, which means 100% of people who have voted have disagreed with you.

Comment: You're throwing around a bunch of baseless inflammatory accusations against a generalized population of prolific contributors while taking offense to constructive criticism from other prolific contributors, I'd call that a rant. I'll put it more bluntly than the previous commentators: do some more research, learn the expectations of the site, and learn from the constructive criticism that those prolific contributors are kind enough to provide for you.

Comment: And to address something specific you said: yes, this site allows users with higher reputation to downvote. Those users have earned the privilege to help enforce quality standards here, and enforcing those standards keep the noise and clutter down and help keep this site a great source of knowledge. If those users didn't do that, this site would be no different than any of the other question sites out there. If that's bothersome to you or you find it unpleasant, you're quite free to take your questions to one of those other sites that have lower standards.

Comment: No problem. I have asked a question and you are expressing your prolific views. I will see if anyone agrees to my humble views. From the point in time I saw two of you join the discussion, you have done well to divert the main point of discussion to more individual focus.

Comment: Cute. There's no *diversion* to *individual focus*. The focus has been to site-wise changes suggested by an inexperienced user who has been here a whole two weeks, and there's no *two of us*. When you're done touting your *vast experience* of *two weeks and having reached > 3K people*, and you're willing to listen to those of us who have been here multiple years and reached multiple millions of users, come back and suggest changing things.

Comment: Where Do Great Ideas Come From? (Hint: It's not always from Where You Think it should!) I am not obsessed or married to your standards yet. Hence, I am giving you an unbiased opinion. Now you may not like it. That is for you to decide. Ok fine, I reached 3K in 2 weeks and in 7 years you reached 11K. Does it matter? My view point had nothing to do with this. I just wanted to say I have seen the people connect.

Comment: Hint: Not from people who know nothing but think they do. If you think differently, suggest a change in medical standards or procedures to your doctor. And look again: I've been here 5 years and *reached > 4.6M people*, not that that means anything, but then again I didn't brag about either of those things). Apparently new users can't always read the reputation pages either or understand what they say. I guess experience does count. But once again, you've gone personal.

Comment: And again, you want to try to personally insult me. Have you not been paying attention? You've already had previous comments flagged and deleted for that; do you need a link to the site's behavior guidelines?

Comment: sigh.... this again. Look. I started actively using the site about 1, 1.5 years ago. NEVER had any issues. I asked a couple of bad questions, got comments like "seriously? Posting a question like this?!" to which I replied "what can I do to make it better". And LO AND BEHOLD! I am not in any kind of trouble, I made my questions better (ended up deleting my first 2, as they were not suited AT ALL for the site). Decided to wait and learn the rules. Adapted to them. Look, Stack is a TOOL like any others. You don't use a hammer to screw, right? Then learn how this tool is used properly....

Comment: Thanks. You've made my point. Those *new users* who you're so fervent about *protecting the interests of* should learn how the site works. It's not *their interests* that need to be protected; it's the interests of the millions of people here who **do** take the time to understand how the site works and what they need to do here before starting to post. And one of the things they should learn from the top is that when they post here asking for input from people, they don't get to pick and choose which people respond and don't get to name-call and insult when those people disagree with them.

Comment: Y'all are so over-defensive. Relax, guys. It's not worth getting worked up about this eighty times a year.

Comment: Its annoying and insulting that you think all new users need protections from the rules. There are plenty of us here capable of reading the help center and acting accordingly.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

> Now, over this short period itself, I have also faced number of people (in some cases people with high reputations) confrontational or engaging in activities which can easily demoralize you.

If you ever see anything genuinely offensive, flag it for moderator attention.  On comments, if you hover over the box, you will see a little "flag".  On posts, you will see an actual "flag" link.

If you see a comment that doesn't really benefit the discussion, you can flag that appropriately; if it doesn't help to clarify the question, "not constructive" is usually fine.

> I felt there could have been more constructive ways to resolve issues but the site allowed people with higher reputations to downvote and at times leave nasty comments to ridicule your question or answers.

Divorce comments from downvotes.

Voting is anonymous by design, and you have no way of guaranteeing that the person commenting on your post has downvoted it.  Again, if the person is leaving genuinely nasty or not constructive comments, flag them appropriately and **do not engage any further** with that person.

However, if your questions *are* being downvoted, think about some reasons why:

- Is your question clear?
- Is your problem well-researched? (Hint:  if it's an easily Googled error message, probably not.)
- Do you have enough information that another person could reasonably reproduce it in their environment?
- Do you have only the essential code needed to reproduce the problem in your question (if your question requires code)?
- Have you made the problem you're trying to solve explicit, what steps you've taken to solve it explicit, and why that hasn't worked for you explicit?  (Again, if you say "it doesn't work", the answer to that is "no".)

> How can we protect the interest levels of new joiners to this site? (especially those who are using genuine ID's)

That's not up to us.  That's up to them.  Stack Overflow is a place that has very exacting standards to what kinds of questions we'll allow here.  Downvotes have their place here, and they're not going to be going away anytime soon; how else would we get rid of poor quality questions?

I won't deny that the standards are pretty demanding; many a user languishes under this, but many of them survive and even thrive here.  If you're willing to take the time and appreciate what it means to ask a question here, and how to ask the question, then we're willing to work with you on a solution.

Comment: I have accepted and gave 1+ve vote your response as these are to the point responses. But please review the comments posted here, some of them were driven mostly by impatience and intolerance.

Comment: @Suparna:  Nah, can't be bothered.  I've said my piece on the matter and my opinion is simply my opinion.  Everyone else is entitled to theirs on this.

Comment: No problem. What was wrong in my question?

Comment: @Suparna:  This question?  On Meta?  Probably just that people disagreed with it, is all.  Don't take it personally.

Comment: @Suparna, it's not simply that people disagree, the problem is that "new comers" **are not** "friendly to the site"... You did not discover a new planet here. If you really want to understand this, just research the archives.

Comment: I don't disagree with your comments. That is why I stated off the bat that - how do we trade-off between spams and good questions/genuine interests to learn!

Comment: That very question has been discussed a million times already. Check the archives.

Answer (score 20):

Examples please.

Hiding behind 'naming and shaming' will not do.  If the commenters' behaviour is that bad, then name them.   Post links to questions where you find unjustified downvotes etc.  (Note: 'unjustified' - general noob downvotes is easy - just block-copy the C tag).

If you do not, then some might suspect that you have no evidence at all and I CAN comment: meta posters with accusations such as yours have been called out before, (as you would have known if you had bothered to seach for duplicates), and asked for evidence.  Nothing whatsoever has been forthcoming that is any better than 'I don't want to give actual examples, but everyone knows it happens'.

After no evidence if forthcoming, I often supply a long list of links to noob nastiness, 'questions' where the posters:

1) Post off-topic questions because they have not bothered to read the rules/policy because I WANT MY ANSWER NOW I DONT HAVE TIME FOR ANYONE ELSES STUPID RULES GIVE ME MY ANSWER

2) Post off-topic questions because they have read the rules/policy but, since that would disallow their question, post it anyway I WANT MY ANSWER NOW THE STUPID RULES DONT APPLY I HAVE TO HAND THIS IN TOMORROW GIVE ME MY ANSWER JUST DO MY HOMEWORK NOW YOU MORONS

3) Post timewasters where Googling the exact title gives: 'About X,XXX,000 results', with many duplicate SO Q&A on the first page that solve the OP's problem.  This can be due to bone-idle deadbeats who cannot be bothered to search and know that, if they post anyway, the drones on SO will do the searching for them.  It can also be a voting ring question.

4) Dumps of complete homework questions.  Anyone who has gone through the educational system recognises the 'Consider, Explain' style of many such questions.  Others have such ridiculous, stupid code that its only possible use would be to demonstrate some specific point or test the understanding of a student.  These questions are often disguised as 'real' problems, and the students are happy to blatantly lie in order to get their answers.

4) Dumps of other peoples' complete homework questions.  Yes, this does happen - 'I do your homework for money' whores post homework that they expect SO slaves to do so that they can get paid.  This often shows up when suggesting a simple fix is met by 'plz post complete code' - OP is totally clueless about programming and clearly did not author the code posted.

5) Questions that imply that the code almost works, and just needs X fixing, when in fact it won't compile and never has. The poster has put in next-to-no effort and wants SO users to fix all their gross grammar/syntax errors, compile, link, test and debug their assignment for free.

6) Questions with so little detail that they are essentialy useless without SO contributors putting in a huge amount of effort, (in parallel); effort that the OP has not made or has put in but has not bothered to tell about.  Any other body of skilled professionals would simply do the work anyway and double the bill but, since SO does not charge, posters think they can be treated badly.

7-XX)  all the other ways in which new users abuse, corrupt and generally waste away the life of SO contributors who are stu.... considerate enough to give them a bit of their spare time.

'confrontational or engaging in activities which can easily demoralize you'

Bah humbug....

Far from being exclusive to high-rep contributors, it's the noobs that are the worst offenders and we are supposed to 'be nice' about it.

Many noobs WILL get heavily downvoted.  They deserve it.

Many noobs WILL get comments that they do not like - they deserve it.

SO does not need such people.   They should go away and waste someone else's life.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36383503/is-floating-point-math-in-c-broken

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36384428/a-pointer-who-initialize-a-char-array-of-structure

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36371372/micro-and-shopping

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36384732/c-insert-variables-in-array

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36384609/compiler-error-for-sorting-an-array

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36384743/input-data-file-to-cauchy-reed-solomon-encoder

[Why are there three zeros followed by the value of the array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36114016/why-are-there-three-zeros-followed-by-the-value-of-the-array)

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36100636/too-few-arguments-to-function-delete-student

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35954975/weird-behaviour-of-operators-in-c

[how to create a #define DEBUG in c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36385037/how-to-create-a-define-debug-in-c)

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36385552/c-why-the-following-code-is-not-crashing

[While loop not working as expected. Code is not fully executed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36385423/while-loop-not-working-as-expected-code-is-not-fully-executed)

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36385199/why-is-my-function-not-working-in-main

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36385083/how-do-i-find-out-how-many-times-this-recursion-was-called

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36385496/enum-in-a-struct

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36385746/kevin-plays-a-gamehackerearth-program

[C can't open file using a variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36385869/c-cant-open-file-using-a-variable)

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36386404/automatic-randomly-clicking-on-area-screen-for-example-100x

This one deserves 5 stars:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36386355/whats-malloc-and-memset

[Functionallity of scanf function in c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36386332/functionallity-of-scanf-function-in-c)

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36386825/c-c-output-of-the-following-code

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36387217/priority-queue-error-in-c

[Why free() in C isn't work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36387276/why-free-in-c-isnt-work)

[CodeChef Small factorial Solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36387013/codechef-small-factorial-solution)

..
..
..

[Still waiting for ONE example of unjustified down/close voting by those nasty, unhelpful, hostile, unconstrictive high-rep users..]
..
..
..

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36387227/trying-to-use-two-consecutive-exec-functions-in-c

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36387614/how-to-code-a-program-that-allow-user-to-choose-resource-city-and-experience-o

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36387606/can-someone-please-explain-to-me-how-and-or-function-work-in-this-code

4-star:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36388053/need-codes-for-active-power-factor-correction-using-atmega8

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36387812/google-test-exercise-fatal-error-limits-file-not-found

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36388668/mergesort-segmentation-fault

4-star:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36395114/how-to-reading-words-from-a-text-file-then-making-an-array-of-those-words

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36396075/test-your-c-skills

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36395094/primary-array-and-enter-an-array-by-user

..
..
..

[Still waiting for ONE example of unjustified down/close voting by those nasty, unhelpful, hostile, unconstrictive high-rep users..]
..
..
..

5-star. it's a killer: contributor: 'You have to put some effort into solving your own problems'.  OP: 'are you kidding me ?'

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36402755/please-help-me-data-structures

OK, as the desert wind hisses across the barren landscape, driving dried tumbleweed towards the next 'hostile, unconstructive, nazi mods' meta post,  I'm calling a halt on my wait for evidence of unjustified downvotes etc. by high-rep users.  Obviously, there is none.

Comment: _"I don't want to give actual examples, but everyone knows it happens"_ - every single Reddit post about Stack Overflow.

Comment: @CodeCaster Yeah, AKA "I don't want to give actual examples, because we haven't actually got any".

Comment: @MartinJames: It's more like "I don't want to give actual examples, because they'd be devastating to my case."

Comment: Well done, Martin.

Comment: 2 times number option 4? Did you get a off-by-one error in your calculation processor, :P

Comment: @Ferrybig I did notice that, but I freely admit being too lazy to fix it, after all, nobody will spot it...........  :)