# How to connect with somebody?

Tags: support

It seems to be common question (maybe it is duplicate), but I cannot find the answer for it. I have a question that is related to one particular library and I have asked questions about it before, and I know one guy, who should know the answer (he answer for questions about it and also he helped me one day). You can imagine how much time you could wait for the answer for very particular question and I really would send a question about my current problem to this guy. But I don't know how I could do this. Creating chat seems to be a bad decision.

Ok, sure I understand, that it might be not so fair in attitude to other potential 'helpers'. But let me know if there is any way to connect with the guy and it is not forbidden.

Comment: If a library author is active on Stack Overflow, and this library has its own tag(s), chances are that this user will regularly check the questions in those tags. Just wait.

Answer (score 9):

Stack Overflow doesn't have a "Private Messaging" feature on purpose.

Users answer on voluntary basis, when they have the time and motivation to do so.
We don't want users poking other users just to get an answer on their question.

*If* the user you want is on chat, you could look for him in a room and ask him for help, but keep in mind that that usually isn't appreciated.

Just post your question on Stack Overflow. Someone *even more* qualified might even answer it.

Comment: I see that you answered also for duplicate of this question. Could you answer another one? Just for my future :) why people downvote this question and the duplicate too? Is it something bad with them except for bad idea? How anybody should ask such questions without very bad reaction?

Comment: @user2216 Take a look at [this meta post](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254108/downvotes-on-meta-are-confusing-do-they-really-mean-poor-post-quality-or-jus?lq=1) for a discussion on voting on Meta.

Comment: Hehe, I didn't remember answering that. At least that answer is pretty much the same as this.

Comment: @user2216 i downvoted your post for lack of research and rehashing a done discussion withouy any new info or arguments. I voted on the other one because i disagree woth it (ultimately i do disagree with yours as well, but i downvoted for other reasons anyway)