# Beyond confused about question and answer reception

Tags: discussion, specific-question, self-answer

Until this morning I was using a non-Anaconda Python interpreter on Windows, but after looking into what I was going to have to do to get SciPy up and running, I chose to install Anaconda. When I went to add the Anaconda interpreter to PyDev, I couldn't find any quick resource on Anaconda's installed location. Neither Google nor the main SO site had an easy-to-lay-your-hands-on answer of where Anaconda places the interpreter. So after some trial and error, I figured out where it was and posted a Q&A on SO that immediately got ravaged:

[Where does Anaconda Python install on Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37117571)

Am I just missing something here? How does a concise, direct question about a standard programming related piece of software without an easily googleable or SO searchable answer not meet the criteria of the site?

I get that it's short. I don't think it needs to be long winded, and I get that some people may already know where this stuff is, but for the life of me I just don't understand the criteria being used to decide the voting and with no comments (no I don't want to go down the "should people leave a comment" path... it leads to the dark side). I'm left to wonder what is so objectionable.

Sorry, the actual question here is: Do you guys see anything in that question you actually think is objectionable that I am missing?

As for all the "It isn't a programming question / not related" comments, it's basically the same thing as this very well received Java question: [Where is Java Installed on Mac OS X?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15826202/where-is-java-installed-on-mac-os-x)

***Update of sorts***

I've been watching the comments both here and on the question all day and frankly I have come to the conclusion that the question just seems to be in a grey area. As of right now the question and answer both have 4 upvotes and 3 downvotes, and though there have been plenty of nay-sayers, questions like the Java one lead me (and presumably the hundreds of folks who up voted the Java question) to believe that there is a place for these type of questions - unless one wants to argue that SO has radically changed in the last 3 years and a question that once received overwhelming support is now off topic.

I also am completely convinced that the community doesn't seem to have a unified vision when it comes to these questions given the comments and actions of those that have visited this and the question page. It looks like there may well be enough close votes to close the question by morning, but based upon what I see in the comments I think I would still pass a question like this through the review ques.

Comment: Yes, I agree that SO is quite unreasonable with its habit of down voting sometimes. It's not enough to follow all the rules here. On other sites, (such as code review), they are MUCH kinder with their voting (if you follow the rules it's easy to get 2 or 3 up votes almost immediately).

Comment: You're just asking where something was installed to, and your answer was to search the hard drive.  Just because the software was anaconda doesn't make it on topic.

Comment: @Will which would be different from this overwhelmingly well received question how? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15826202/where-is-java-installed-on-mac-os-x

Comment: Ugh, that's pretty awful.  Unfortunately, for every type of off topic question, you can probably find an older, upvoted example of the same thing.

Comment: The more I look into that question the more I vomit.  Look at OP's answer on it--"Uh, I didn't install what I thought I installed DERP" Only java developers would upvote that nonsense.  It's the worst thing I've seen on SO in a long time.  Here's some upvotes for finding that festering boil.

Comment: It's the same rubbish as the devs who would rather spam SO with a question than grep for their missing/bad declaration in the .h files:(  'Only java developers would upvote that nonsense' LOL!

Comment: @Will What makes it off-topic? Questions about tools commonly used by programmers are explicitly [not off topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). SO is designed to be a repository of knowledge and answers, not a contest to create the most difficult and interesting questions. Also, OPs answer was not 'search the hard drive', it explicitly gives a path for future viewers.

Comment: Rob is right about SO not being a competition.  Also, self-answered questions always seem to get a bad reception, despite being explicitly encouraged.

Comment: the main difference between you and the "Java on OSX" question is that the latter question actually listed research and places the author looked for it before asking. You said "whoops can't find it, didn't search my hard drive for it, please help" so the natural inclination is -- you're a programmer, you should know how to search a hard drive?

Comment: @JeffAtwood But it's an immediately self-answered question. Showing "research" is of *arguable* value *most* of the time (anything beyond "this obvious approach `foo(bar)` looks like it should work but fails with a BlaError" or "there's nothing on the relevant [docs page](http://example.com)" is *usually* excessive, IMO, and even ordinary questions can be useful without that much, but most questions show *far more* than that). Making up some bullshit failed "research" to show for a self-answered question where you already know the correct answer, on the other hand, is just outright pointless.

Comment: it just doesn't seem worth the minimal amount of effort -- typing up this meta question was probably 10x the effort -- and ultimately comes across as self-serving, as a way to generate rep based on a question I'm not sure anyone actually _has_. Clearly lots of people had the Java on OSX question. That's not the case here.. overall it just feels bad to see this sort of question and answer pair out there. Where's the effort? Where's the _utility to others?_ So I'm not surprised it got downvoted.

Comment: @JeffAtwood I don't much care about effort, but I agree that it's a little ugly to see the question getting lots of upvotes that are clearly from meta voters; that's significant rep being gathered without *any* utility to others being demonstrated. I disagree that the question clearly doesn't have such utility; the asker clearly needed to know this information, so it's entirely realistic that other people will too. I don't like the Meta upvoters, but I *also* don't like the downvoters, because *neither* of them seem to really be voting based on evidence of the question's utility.

Comment: Just cast the final reopening vote. Your question is good.

Comment: @Renan thanks for that. I appreciate the vote of confidence.

Comment: As for showing research effort - if I have the same doubt as the OP and I am looking for a solution, I don't care about what does not work - I care about what works. If I see a question where the OP says "I have tried A, B and C and they didn't work", then A, B and C are noise. I would edit those out of the question to make it more concise.

Comment: I think there is a bit of class division here...for expert programmers, questions like this have no utility, but for the novice programmers (who will always outnumber the experts) it does. It's [slightly] elitist to say "you're a programmer, you should know how to search a hard drive."  I've been programming for 30 years, and I still learn new, basic things on SO all the time.  I think this question is offensive to those who expect/hope for SO to NOT be a resource for novice users, which it clearly has become.  In my opinion, there's plenty of room for everyone here.

Comment: @JeffAtwood Research effort is bullshit - you're saying the OSX question is better because it has a bunch of pointless noise in the question. I want to see clear, precise questions - not paragraphs of guesses by OP that I have to wade through to find it.

Comment: If this is deemed on topic, shouldn't I just create a long series of similar questions. Q: Where is X installed on Windows? A: Use ```where``` to find out. Replacing X with a series of programmer tools?

Comment: I'm with @Gilles - how to find particular file in Windows is on-topic (probably dup) on SU, but really does not look valid on SO. I can see OSX users unable to use underlying OS commands, but Windows has both UI and CLI search...

Comment: I'm just here to say nice to see you @Jeff Atwood

Comment: @Renan: "I tried A, B, and C" is **not** noise! With, potential answerers can avoid the obvious and get right to the solution; without, a slew of comments may follow, all in the vein "why not try A?" "I tried A and it failed because .." "What about B?"

Comment: @RadLexus If you have to say "why not A", the question was not clear enough. If the OP has to say "I have tried A, B and C", they need a rubber duck.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Not sure I can directly answer your question, but I can comment on the factors that seem to come into play as questions are responded to, as the site collectively winnows the "good questions" from the "bad questions".  (But the problem is, obviously enough, that there lots of conflicting definitions of "good" and "bad".  I'm going to list some reasons, but without necessarily agreeing with them, or accusing you personally of having "violated" them.)

1. Some people think that the site is targeted at programmers with at least a certain level of experience.  If you're not at that level, you shouldn't be asking basic questions here, you should be off reading books or taking classes, rather than asking questions which may be hard to answer without teaching you those basics, which isn't necessarily this site's job.
2. Most people think that the site is targeted at programmers who are working on something but have gotten stuck at a particular point and need help getting past it.  Most people think that the site is *not* for doing your homework for you, or writing your program for you, or doing your job for you.
3. Some people think that if the answer is obviously easily answered by oneself, it shouldn't be asked here.
4. Some/many/most (I really don't know what percentage) people think that the site is *not* primarily about helping you, but rather, about building a repository of high-quality answers that others might find useful.  So every new question is viewed through this lens, and questions that don't pass muster are downvoted, put on hold, closed, or not answered.

But it's pretty obvious that the various contributors here are all over the map when it comes to how they apply these criteria.  Everybody's threshold of the "certain level of experience" in #1 is different.  Everybody has different ideas of where the line is between "helping you past a stuck point" versus "doing your work for you" on #2 and #3.  And there's even more variation on #4, because whether a question is actually "high quality" and worthy of inclusion in the repository is almost totally subjective, and there are few if any written guidelines.  And, finally, some volunteers don't care about the repository at all, and are willing to just help you regardless of whether it's likely that anyone else will ever ask your exact question again.

Me, I don't see anything wrong with the question that sparked this thread.  But I suspect that the people who downvoted or otherwise complained about it felt that it fell down (for them) on some combination of #3 and #4.

Finally, it's unfortunately true that, once a question has been downvoted, there's almost nothing you can do about it.  No matter how "good" the question might have actually been, no matter how unjust the downvoting might have been (and, I agree, quite often it seems pretty rampantly unjust), there's almost no way to ask about it that doesn't end up sounding like, well, whining, and getting you almost no sympathy.  (I'm not saying that you, or any of the many others who have asked such questions, are whining.  But it, quite unfortunately, tends to sound that way, so you tend to be kind of stuck.)

Comment: yeah I think it is just boiling down to different people's perception of what the community is here for especially given the massive number of up and down votes that the question generated in a day as well as the fact that it was closed and reopened within a matter of hours.

Answer (score 17):

If this weren't self-answered, it would just be a lack of research effort.

It *is* self-answered, so my view is a little different, but no less negative I'm afraid: if the answer were specific to Anaconda and not immediately obvious from the Anaconda documentation, then perhaps it would have some utility.

But it's not. It's totally generic, a "where is $Program installed on Windows?" The Anaconda factor is entirely tangential. So, even as a self-answered question, I don't see much utility here.

In fact, the question doesn't even specify a version of Windows, or a version of Anaconda! So on that basis alone it's not a particularly good question.

Now, I'm not going to sit here and claim that you posted it only for repwhoring — I don't at all believe that you did. But as it is so generic, so broad, and so trivial, I don't think it's a particularly useful addition to the repository and as a self-answered question I can see why some people are questioning why it was posted if not to generate reputation.

So, I wouldn't have posted a Q&A like that.

However, now that it *has* been posted, and given that it'll probably save someone else from having to do the two minutes' research (which is apparently our baseline amount of effort nowadays), I would not vote to close or remove it.

Answer (score 10):

I wouldn't say your Q&A was *ravaged*, but rather, not well-received. Here are my thoughts:

#### The question

I can see why the question was downvoted. The downvote tooltip on questions states

> This question does not show any research effort; it is unclear or not useful

While I can appreciate that perhaps it took you a rather long time to find where it was installed, I can think of various other things to find the default install, all of them quicker than asking SO.

That being said, if Google doesn't have an accurate result on the first page, I'm not against seeing a question asked that helps people find that answer.

In summary, those **not** familiar with the difficulty in installing it might interpret the question as "where can I find something" where they assume the something is rather easy to find.

---

#### The answer

I see nothing wrong (well, besides a minor spelling mistake) with the answer.

---

#### The QA as a whole

Having said all that, and with no proof (these are just my thoughts remember), although [posting Q&A](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/) and [self-answering questions is on-topic and encouraged](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer), they often aren't well received, but no worse than just questions in general. I've found that the more advanced topics and longer answers (longer tends to go hand-in-hand with better explained + more information) are better received. Without trying to draw attention, [this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31974237/why-is-libcs-vectorboolconst-reference-not-bool) was well-received

It *may* be worth adding information to the question (referencing help material) that doesn't help, as well as linking similar questions for while you feel it's on-topic

Note that the scope of what is considered on/off-topic changes over time, so referencing things several years old isn't necessarily a good guide.

Comment: Although I'm [aware downvotes on Meta are different](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254108/downvotes-on-meta-are-confusing-do-they-really-mean-poor-post-quality-or-jus), it would be helpful to me to know _what_ about my post you disagree with or don't like. Did you disagree with something in particular, or the whole post in general?

Comment: I think that if someone downvotes an answer in meta but doesn't take the time or effort to justify it in comments, it simply means they don't like it. Haters gonna hate, so just let it be. And have my upvote.

Comment: This "I have no recourse but to ask for help if I don't get my answer on the first page of Google results" attitude is horrifically damaging for our industry. I really wish it would go away.