# Is there any sanction for askers who should know better not accepting an answer?

Tags: discussion, accepted-answer

I've recently decided to take the plunge and start answering a few questions, where I can.

I can still remember (cannot we all?) what it is like to be a newbie.  Questions are not properly formatted, code and example data is not provided, etc.  Despite all this answers are given (mostly politely). Answers are not always acknowledged.  But this is to be forgiven.

But I feel we should expect more of seasoned users. If a seasoned user does not behave reasonably, should there not be some mechanism to detract from their reputation?

What is reasonable behaviour?

Suppose [you ask a question and receive an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39106800/rounding-decimal-when-the-last-significant-digit-is-5/39107079#39107079); in my view, above a certain reputation level (say 500), you should be expected either to accept the answer, within a given grace period after you next logged on, or to post a comment explaining why the answer was inadequate.  I would go even further and require an acceptance, not a comment, if the answer exceeded 2 up votes (the minimum for an auto-bounty), or, failing which, a self given answer.  Note, if a self-given answer is provided in an attempt to avoid sanction, the answer can be down-voted, which has a reputation cost.  Failure to do so should incur a reputation penalty by default.

I welcome any other suggestions, but I do think something should be done.

Comment: Well there you go.  Within three minutes I get 4 down votes and not a single comment.  In my view, that sums up everything that is wrong with this site.  Goodbye.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov The actual proposal is clear enough.  It's an awful idea, but not unclear.  Lots of noise before he gets there, granted.

Comment: search for [downvote require comment is:question](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=downvote+require+comment+is%3Aquestion) shows 61 results

Comment: @JonathanWillcock You already had two answers before you even posted that comment explaining/demonstrating why your proposal is a bad idea.  You also state that you think users with >500 rep should be held to a high standard when asking questions; to then say that your (very poorly researched) question shouldn't be held to that high standard is quite hypocritical.

Comment: *but I do think something should be done* Why?  I get that getting 15 rep is nice but is it worth really worth all this?  If you think having the accepted answer means your answer is the accepted(by the community) answer then I suggest you check out why we have [Populist Badge](http://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/62/populist)

Comment: Also note that [voting is different on meta](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254108/downvotes-on-meta-are-confusing-do-they-really-mean-poor-post-quality-or-jus)

Comment: @gnat: Stupid though this question is, that is not a duplicate of it. That question is about users who "never ever, ever accepts answers". This question is about a user who clearly does accept answers. He simply hasn't accepted this one. Yet. Which in fact makes this question *worse*. At least the other was is dealing with a genuine (if rather trivial) problem.

Comment: @NicolBolas I would reject the statement that the other answer is a problem either.

Answer (score 34):

So what seems to have prompted this is that you left an answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39106800/rounding-decimal-when-the-last-significant-digit-is-5), an answer that was upvoted by four members of the community. However, the asker has not yet accepted your answer.

Askers are under no obligation to accept answers, at any reputation level. It's perfectly fine if they never accept an answer. Sometimes it takes a while to verify that a solution works or does not. Sometimes they feel that no answer fully satisfies their needs. This isn't being rude.

The only problem here was the series of comments you left:

> @Richard77 You are experienced enough here to know better. Why is it, when someone answers your question (with to date 4 up votes), you do not bother to respond? That is the behaviour I expect from newbies. Are you simply embarassed, that someone with so inferior reputation to yours, has provided the correct answer?
>
> @Richard77 Why ask a question, if you do not want an answer?
>
> @Richard77 17 Gold, 69 Silver, 131 bronze last seen 24 mins ago, so you must have seen my answer. I feel like quitting StackOverflow. What is the point?
>
> @Richard77 17 answers 481 questions. Says it all.

These *were* rude and I deleted all of them. If someone doesn't accept your answer, move on. Don't harass them about it. People can already see from the votes that your answer was a good one, and you've earned more points from those votes than an accept vote.

Comment: I was tempted not to upvote this absolutely correct answer simply so Servy's brilliant answer remains the highest voted, but in the end common sense prevailed... +1

Comment: @psubsee2003 - Even better, it illustrates another reason for not accepting an answer: you can't choose between two good ones.

Answer (score 31):

I'm posting this as a completely unacceptable answer to this question that I sincerely hope the question author finds unsatisfactory, with the knowledge that they should feel obligated to accept it anyway after two days if nobody else bothers to post an answer to this question.

Comment: I find this answer entertainingly ironic.

Comment: @Makoto While the one half get's to their garage to fetch the torches and pitchforks, the other goes to the kitchen for fetching popcorn and cola ;) Ah, and I found some tar and feathers in my hobby room as well.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ:  You've got some strange hobbies there.  Want some popcorn instead?

Comment: If only it were Friday, @πάνταῥεῖ; then we could just dive into the sausages and beer!

Comment: @Makoto Don't worry, we can have it alltogether. You just need to take care what you want to eat or drink of all that stuff.

Comment: This is a comment that serves absolutely no purpose. Except to light up Servy's notifications unnecessarily.

Comment: Am i the only one tempted to find a way to get the other answers deleted just to see if this one gets accepted?

Comment: @Pekka웃 Apparently I'm not allowed to accept that comment.  Must be a bug.

Answer (score 13):

Sadly, Brad Larson erased your comments. I say "sadly" because it prevents doing a bit of forensic analysis to determine when you started complaining about them.

However, one thing seems clear: Larson deleted your comments about 28 hours after you posted your answer. Which means that you started bugging the OP no later than 28 hours after you posted your answer.

You are not complaining about a user who habitually doesn't accept answers; the user's profile shows this to not be the case. You are therefore complaining that the user did not accept your answer ***quickly enough***.

A little over a day has passed. You have no idea what happened with this person in that day. Maybe he went on vacation. Maybe he had a long day at work and hasn't gotten back to SO.

Or maybe he's just waiting for a couple of days to see if his question attracts any other answers before making his choice.

You do not have the right to an accept checkmark within 24 hours of your answer. You do not have the right to an accept checkmark ***at all***. If the OP doesn't want to accept your answer, that is *his right*. Unless he's doing so to abuse the system in some way, you have no right to question it.

Who are *you* to say that he's misbehaving by not accepting *your* answer as fast as you would prefer?

Answer (score 10):

You should probably take a chill pill.  Just because the OP doesn't respond in any way that you can identify doesn't mean that your answer has necessarily been ignored.  Heck, the OP isn't obligated *at all* to respond to your answer.

However, by you going after them in the comments section antagonizing them, you do open yourself up because those sorts of comments aren't constructive.

Let it go, man.  So far, four people have found your answer useful.  That should be plenty of affirmation.

Comment: I take chill pills like popcorn BTW. Just doesn't help most of the time. You've got my upvote anyway.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Just to note: no amount of sugar, salt or butter should be added to the chill pill, nor should they be heated. It is to be taken in all its natural glory.

Answer (score -17):

1. If someone asks a question, gets a perfectly decent answer, whereby the person answering could not be certain (and said as much) due to the question not being specific enough, and then ignores the answer, despite re-visiting the site, then in my view the questioner is being rude.  Everyone here seems to be under the impression, that I was cross that my answer was not "accepted".  No, I was cross because the questioner did not at least comment, bearing in mind that my answer was a supposition, based on the lack of detail in the question.  I perfectly understand that some people prefer to await a potentially better answer before accepting, because you can only accept one answer.  But where an answer requires some reaction from the questioner, I do expect an experienced questioner to respond in some way.
2. To all of you who say that there is no compunction to accept an answer, I make one simple point.  In answering a question, we are not simply helping the questioner, but hopefully all successive users of the site.  I can only speak from personal experience, but, in the past, when I have searched for answers, I was drawn firstly to similar questions with accepted answers, secondly to similar questions with high upvoted unaccepted answers, and as a last resort to unaccepted answers with low upvotes.  I very much doubt that I am alone.  So, as stated in 1) above, whilst I accept that it is perfectly OK to wait before accepting an answer, I do believe that experienced site users should either accept an answer, or leave a good comment / edit their question to explain why no given answer is acceptable.  Clearly, though, I seem to be in a minority of 1 on this point.
3. Again I can only speak for myself, but when searching through questions in an attempt to help others, I always look at questions in my favourite tags with no answers.  I mostly (but I must admit not always) look at questions with no accepted answers, in case I can give a better answer.  I very rarely look at questions with accepted answers.  But, as in 2) above, I again doubt that I am alone.  Therefore, the failure on the part of a questioner to respond to a decent answer in any way, is, in my view, wasting the time of potential answerers, who would otherwise concentrate their efforts on other questions.  Again my comments here are particularly focussed on experienced users.
4. As to the point of a questioner "Going on vacation", I really find it hard to take this objection seriously.  What is the point of asking a question just before heading off to the beach, with no intention of looking at the answers till after their return?  What if potential answerers required clarification in order to help?  Really, if that is the best that some of you can do, then shame on you.

With so far 33 down votes, not to mention a good deal of ridicule, I regretfully realise, that my views on the behaviour that one should reasonably expect of experienced users are not only not shared but in fact are so far away from the general view, that my continued presence here is undesirable to all concerned.  I therefore bid you all adieu.

Edit

At the risk of another wave of down votes before the expiry runs out on my profile, I would be grateful if someone could explain what happened last night. I was convinced to leave the site by someone posting words to the effect, "if you say you are going, why do you keep coming back. Do us all a favour and make up your mind." In response, I immediately actioned the account delete. I notice however that the comment is no longer there. Is there any way to find out if a moderator deleted it or the user himself? Obviously if they had hoped that I had not seen it, then sorry too late, damage done.

Comment: I wouldn't leave just because you gathered a few downvotes. It happens, people disagree and but it's the internet, don't let it get to you.  If you can answer questions and contribute positively why let someone drive you away?  Good luck!

Comment: "*then in my view the questioner is being rude*" You are the one who answered a question that was "not being specific enough". If it's not specific enough to be answered, then you had no business guessing at an answer to it. If you felt that your answer was a guess, then it is *you* who should have commented to explicitly ask for clarification. Answers should never "require some reaction from the questioner". That's not how Q&A works, and that's *far* more fundamental to this site's well-being than a person who didn't accept an answer on one of their questions.

Comment: 1. You don't know what is going on in the life of the other person. It's absolutely up to them if they want/can react. Make your life easier by not expecting any response. Your answer is not there to only help OP, you'll help others as well.

Comment: "*in the past, when I have searched for answers, I was drawn firstly to similar questions with accepted answers*" When I do searches, Google leads me to a question that matches what I typed in. I then get an ordered list of answers, starting with the accepted one (if any). I don't evaluate questions based on whether they've had an accepted answer or not. If for no other reason than that Google doesn't provide that information.

Comment: 2. If you are looking for the best answer, you should look for highly upvoted answers first (and ignore acceptance marks). OP will not always have accepted the answer that is the best.

Comment: "*the failure on the part of a questioner to respond to a decent answer in any way, is, in my view, wasting the time of potential answerers, who would otherwise concentrate their efforts on other questions.*" That presupposes that your answer *is correct*. That it *ought to be accepted*. And that anyone else who looks at the question would instantly say "yep, that's the answer." Sorry, but I don't buy that.

Comment: "*What if potential answerers required clarification in order to help?*" Then the question will be closed as unclear until they return and provide the needed information. Just like *any other question*. You do not have the right to expect a timely response from *anyone* on such things. Vote to close (or flag if you can't do that) and move on.

Comment: 4. Imagine OP not heading off to the beach, but to the hospital because a family member got worse. There _are_ things much more important than being on stand-by on SO.

Comment: @ᴉʞuǝ Many thanks for your comment.  Unfortunately yours seems to have been a lone voice.  I have therefore instigated the profile removal system.  I never realised it took so long - more than 48 hours will have elapsed from my request to it being actioned.  I wish you well.

Comment: @Nikol Bolas We obviously disagree on too many things for it to be worthwhile persuing the point.  But one point I think is particularly relevant.  Whilst you are correct that Google will lead you toward a particular question (and naturally not just on SO), once you do land on SO, on the right hand side you get the Related panel.  Here accepted answers are in a solid green box.  I would respectfully suggest that the reason the designers have done this is precisely to draw users attention to it.  You choose to ignore this, others do not.