# Is there a way to view edits that I have already approved?

Tags: support, edits, suggested-edits, approval

**tl;dr** If I (with high permissions) approve an edit (done with low permissions) I would like to see the edit's effect at once even if the original editor needs several approvals to activate their edit.  (Alternatively my approval as high-permission user should be enough to activate the edit.)

Often I edit questions to fix the formatting of (e. g. unindented) source code.  This also is necessary for me to be able to really understand the question.  So I like it that once I finished editing a question it appears (to me) with my edits already active.

If somebody else already did the work, however, I only can "approve" this edit and typically then it needs to be approved by some more people to be active and visible, even to me.  I then continue to see the unedited (unformatted) version of the questions which makes it hard to read, so I often skip this question and wait until the edit gets approved by other people so it is active for me as well.

Maybe this is an issue of me having higher privileges than the first editor (so that my edits do not need to get approval).

In any case, I would like to see any edits I approved at once.  If it is a privilege issue, my approval should activate the edit at once.

Or is there any way, maybe a trick, for me to get the edited version visible?  (I understand that if I enter the edit mode again which shows a rendered preview below, I will have this, but I would prefer to not need to do this as it clearly is a hack, prevents me from starting writing an answer and risks unintended edits.)

Comment: You, as a user with full edit privileges,  could do an "Improve Edit" instead of *approve* and then submit. That will apply the pending edit and your *improvement*. Some call this abuse, some call this *work with the system*, YMMV.

Comment: Wow, I'd be interested what caused the three downvotes on my question (without any explanation).  My fault must be extremely obvious, yet I just fail to see it.  This is rather discouraging for users to use Meta at all.

Comment: @rene Thank you, I think that would solve my issue.  I will try this next time.

Comment: @Alfe 3 downvotes on your question and 10 upvotes on Rene's question, is it possible that they all thought that Rene's comment covered the points that they downvoted for?

Comment: @Draken I don't see a reason for a downvote of this Q in Rene's comment (you meant that, I assume) either.  I only see a nice little workaround for the problem, not a critique on my question.  Am I just blind?

Comment: Or is downvoting a Q on Meta to be understood as an "I do not second that" or "I vote for nothing to be done on this issue (because an acceptable workaround exists)"?  That would explain the downvotes for sure (because of the workaround Rene provided).

Comment: @Alfe Sorry, meant comment. As for downvoting on meta, see [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254108/downvotes-on-meta-are-confusing-do-they-really-mean-poor-post-quality-or-jus)

Comment: @Draken Yeah, well, my question was changed from a "bug" (how I declared it and which I felt it is because it doesn't make sense to hide an improvement from my eyes just because someone else found this before me) to a "support" issue, but neither is a "feature-request".  And the two close-requests on my question also aren't explained by a non-supportive vote.  Thanks for pointing to the other Q anyway.

Comment: I've re-read your question and I'm afraid due to some methods of putting your view across and the way I read it, I've misunderstood. I originally read it as is there any way to improve someone else's edit. However, and correct me if I'm wrong, you instead mean you've approved an edit, that doesn't need further improvement but must wait further validation until the updated question is visible and would instead like to see the updated version since you've already approved it. I feel your question might need some extra clarification, maybe add a TDLR?

Comment: I think it is a legit question so don't worry about that. On meta votes are given frivolous in either direction. Sometimes you hope those meta voters go sit in the [tag:android] tag for 6 to 8 days. My comment is a *trick* that  you asked for. I didn't want to post it as a full answer as I don't want to advocate to use loopholes as common practice. The comment upvotes are probably from those that either know the trick or found it useful. We don't know how many dislike that trick. All we know is that none of the visitors so far wanted to leave a comment to reprimand me for revealing the trick.

Comment: @Draken Oh, I wasn't aware that my post was maybe misunderstood; thanks for pointing that out.  (Still, I think a downvote without an explanation is never a good thing.)  I added the tl;dr you proposed.  I hope you didn't mean a [TDLR](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=tdlr); I don't like being so rude ;-)

Comment: @Alfe Sorry Alfe, I did mean TLDR. Dam difficult typing on the phone at times... ;)

Answer (score 3):

> If I (with high permissions) approve an edit (done with low
>   permissions) I would like to see the edit's effect at once...

IIRC, this already exists for users under 2K rep: when a user suggests an edit to a post, they do continue to see the edited version of of the post with a message that other users will see the unedited version until it is approved. It seems like this should be possible to display for reviewers as well, with the message being that the edit is waiting for additional reviews.

However, I don't think they'd dedicate resources to make this happen without support for the feature request and right now it doesn't look like you have it.

That said, I think in most cases you can make a legitimate Improve Edit to a suggested edit that only fixes code formatting. My experience in the review queue is that I end up improving 60% of the edits I approve and some of my regular Approves were a matter of not having the time/knowledge/mental resources to make other changes.