# Improved font for code?

Tags: feature-request, fonts

The font used for code doesn't distnguish well between `1` (one) and `l` (lowercase L). 
This has led to a very difficult to fix error. I usually pride myself on catching these "rookie errors", but it caught me this time. I think this is a really important issue for non-expert users and even expert users of stackoverflow!

I wonder if the font could be improved? For example deja vu mono and ubuntu mono all have nice curled l's.

### edit:

The offending line was the instruction for installing a network device driver

```
sudo dkms add ./rtl8814AU
```

which I mistakenly read as `rt18814AU` (post was [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/879187/asus-usb-ac68-0b051817-drivers/879258#879258)).

I had to read the page on my phone. The reason it was a problem is that I had to read from my phone and type the commands into my command line, since I had no net connection on the computer in question. The difficulty reading was on android firefox, but I see the same problem on ubuntu  and windows.

Alexei's answer was very useful; on Ubuntu I'm getting Liberation Mono, and on windows I get Consolas. Both of these fonts have very difficult-to-distinguish l/1.

Here is Consolas

[image]

Liberation:

[image]

Dejavu

[image]

Now I'm not arguing that they are indistinguishable - indeed it's obvious when you zoom in. I'm just saying that I think amateurs or beginners are more likely to make mistakes with the current font order, and would be better off with dejavu.

Comment: `1` and `l` are *very* legible on my computer.  What font is your browser configured to use for monospace?

Comment: Providing clear MRE is the question's author responsibility. If they decided to name everying `l` and `I` and `1` that really look more like trolling than honest attempt at MRE. Plus the question at the end will have to be closed as "type" most likely...

Comment: @Makoto Interestingly, the [monospace in questions is clear for me but not in comments](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kd2et.jpg). But I guess nobody cares because I’m using the app.

Comment: OP, which of the fonts in Alexei Levenkov's answer do you have on your machine? You're either seeing one of the first few listed fonts, and don't like it, or you don't have the ones you suggested either and are seeing the "monospace" font. You might just need to install the font you're asking for.

Comment: I am sad my question has been downvoted so I am sorry if this is off topic or badly written. But just so you don't think I'm mad, I've added some info above.

Comment: @SanjayManohar Downvotes on meta is likely because people do not agree with you. Not because your Question is badly written.

Comment: [How do I participate in Meta and not die trying?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/44188/how-do-i-participate-in-meta-and-not-die-trying) and [Downvotes on Meta are confusing: do they *really* mean poor-post quality, or just disagreement?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254108/downvotes-on-meta-are-confusing-do-they-really-mean-poor-post-quality-or-jus)

Comment: I think a better font would a great idea, and I find the bottem-left serif on lowercase `l` to be unfortunately surprising. Other fonts I'm used to don't have this serif. OP is not alone: https://stackoverflow.com/a/96288/5023438

Answer (score 4):

I don't think this is a necessary feature as I yet to see on-topic post where this would be a problem. If really necessary just grab MRE from the post and paste in your editor of choice which will instantly color variables and literals differently with your favorite font.

While picking fonts is nice topic I don't think this particular reason is promoting right behavior on the site - helping to post code that is hard to read (all variables named `l` or `a23`, `a38` or any other hard to understand scheme) is not what we want.

Note that it looks like the site's CSS already have wide selection of code-friendly fonts for variety of platforms/browsers. And your suggestion to use "DejaVu Sans Mono" is the current behavior of the site. If you prefer serif versions of fonts I think it would be easier to have custom CSS/font substitution rather than request it as site wide feature.

```
font-family: 
      Consolas,
      Menlo,
      Monaco,
      Lucida Console,
      Liberation Mono,
      DejaVu Sans Mono,
      Bitstream Vera Sans Mono,
      Courier New,
      monospace,
      sans-serif;
```