# Auto-format user link?

Tags: support, hyperlinks, user-experience

We know that question links are "beautified" like so:

`https://stackoverflow.com/q/67193740/11573842`

would be rendered as:

[How can I ceck the existence of `expect_out(buffer)` (and related)?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/67193740/11573842)

and not as `https://stackoverflow.com/q/67193740/11573842` (verbatim).

I provided an answer citing a user's profile link.

I noticed that (as opposed to question links) the link is not "beautified", but is displayed verbatim.

> [image]

I was hoping that the link would look like this ("auto beautified" like question links are):

> [image]

Is that intentional?

Comment: Yes, I think it's intentional. What would you want the link to look like instead?

Comment: Comments have never had a shortened link.

Comment: @cigien See the example and the comment. I think it's very obvious.

Comment: I'm sorry, but it's not obvious to me what the problem is, and what you want to happen. Your question is composed of only one sentence. Why not expand on your question a little, ideally with examples?

Comment: @cigien I still think it's very obvious, but as you like downvoting, I'll add the obvious to make you see.

Comment: As an aside, I would *strongly* suggest not assuming that specific users are downvoting your content, and you should definitely avoid mentioning that to other users. I don't care personally, but a lot of users are offended by that, and you're likely to invite even more downovtes as a result.

Comment: @cigien Generally (after having seen *many* questions) I got the impression that here (meta stackoverflow) questions are more radically downvoted than anywhere else. If this question deserves a `-15`, then most other questions would deserve `-3000` or even less.

Comment: I don't disagree that voting on Meta is broken, or at least, it's very unclear what the votes mean. A vote could be because of the *quality* of the question, or the *utility* of the question, or a number of other reasons, and figuring out what they mean in aggregate is a pointless task. Anyway, you seem to be focusing a lot more on the voting on this question, than the question itself (to the extent that the posted answer mentions it). I would suggest discussing voting in a separate Meta. If you do decide to post a Meta about that, make sure to do the research first; this has come up before.

Answer (score 6):

I think that you're referring to the fact that links to other questions will automatically be replaced with the title. In this case, though, it's a link to a user account (not a question or even a comment), which I assume was simply not implemented on the SE site. (It's not very common to link to user accounts in questions or answers, so this kind of a feature would probably be low value). The correct link to the comment that I assume that you're referring to is: `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67193740/how-can-i-ceck-the-existence-of-expect-outbuffer-and-related/67196034#comment118774087_67193740`

Also, I would encourage you not to take downvotes personally (especially on Meta, where they have a different meaning than they do on the main site). See the [Help Center article on Meta](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-meta) as well as [Downvotes on Meta are confusing: do they *really* mean poor-post quality, or just disagreement?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254108/downvotes-on-meta-are-confusing-do-they-really-mean-poor-post-quality-or-jus)

One other thing to read: [Why isn't providing feedback mandatory on downvotes, and why are ideas suggesting such negatively received?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/357436/why-isnt-providing-feedback-mandatory-on-downvotes-and-why-are-ideas-suggestin)

Comment: OK, so your answer is "*simply not implemented*". That's OK. Reading https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/357436/why-isnt-providing-feedback-mandatory-on-downvotes-and-why-are-ideas-suggestin I got the impression that you downvote the question when you don't want to implement an obvious solution ("We're not here to write your code for you, newbie!!"). However I think it would be better someone would provide an answer saying "We plan to change that" and people downvote that answer instead. Doesn't down-voting a question mean it will be closed? If so I think that's simply wrong (MHO).

Comment: Also: My question was tagged `support` (not `enhancement`). So downvoting that based on the semantics (not syntax) is like you don't want to answer that question. That just feels wrong.

Comment: I actually didn't vote on the question either way.

Comment: "You" is plural ;-)